# How does using conda to install a package change my python version and remove conda?

Tags: anaconda, conda

I had been using Anaconda with python 2.7

```
$ python
Python 2.7.14 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec  7 2017, 17:05:42) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

When I decided to install tensorflow (since for some reason I had the non-gpu version)

The command I used was:

```
$ conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu
```

However, after it was done (detail on output of this cmd to follow), I no longer had conda:

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge keras
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/anaconda2/bin/conda", line 12, in <module>
    from conda.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'
```

(Note: I also no longer had Keras) and was now running Python 3.7(!?):

```
$ python
Python 3.6.8 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Dec 30 2018, 01:22:34) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

What happened? How do I stop it from happening again? This happened once before and I ended up deleting all my anaconda files, then reinstalling. I don't want to make that a habit.

The output of my `conda install` was:

```
$ conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /home/me/anaconda2

  added / updated specs:
    - tensorflow-gpu


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    _tflow_190_select-0.0.1    |              gpu           2 KB  anaconda
    absl-py-0.7.0              |           py36_0         156 KB  anaconda
    astor-0.7.1                |           py36_0          43 KB  anaconda
    c-ares-1.15.0              |       h7b6447c_1          98 KB  anaconda
    ca-certificates-2018.12.5  |                0         123 KB  anaconda
    certifi-2018.11.29         |           py36_0         146 KB  anaconda
    cudatoolkit-9.0            |       h13b8566_0       340.4 MB  anaconda
    cudnn-7.1.2                |        cuda9.0_0       367.8 MB  anaconda
    cupti-9.0.176              |                0         1.6 MB  anaconda
    curl-7.63.0                |    hbc83047_1000         145 KB  anaconda
    gast-0.2.2                 |           py36_0         138 KB  anaconda
    git-2.11.1                 |                0         9.5 MB  anaconda
    grpcio-1.16.1              |   py36hf8bcb03_1         1.1 MB  anaconda
    krb5-1.16.1                |       h173b8e3_7         1.4 MB  anaconda
    libcurl-7.63.0             |    h20c2e04_1000         550 KB  anaconda
    libedit-3.1.20181209       |       hc058e9b_0         188 KB  anaconda
    libssh2-1.8.0              |       h1ba5d50_4         233 KB  anaconda
    markdown-3.0.1             |           py36_0         107 KB  anaconda
    mkl_fft-1.0.10             |   py36ha843d7b_0         170 KB  anaconda
    mkl_random-1.0.2           |   py36hd81dba3_0         407 KB  anaconda
    ncurses-6.1                |       he6710b0_1         958 KB  anaconda
    numpy-1.15.4               |   py36h7e9f1db_0          47 KB  anaconda
    numpy-base-1.15.4          |   py36hde5b4d6_0         4.3 MB  anaconda
    openssl-1.1.1              |       h7b6447c_0         5.0 MB  anaconda
    pip-18.1                   |           py36_0         1.8 MB  anaconda
    protobuf-3.5.2             |   py36hf484d3e_1         610 KB  anaconda
    python-3.6.8               |       h0371630_0        34.4 MB  anaconda
    qt-4.8.7                   |                2        34.1 MB  anaconda
    setuptools-40.6.3          |           py36_0         625 KB  anaconda
    six-1.12.0                 |           py36_0          22 KB  anaconda
    sqlite-3.26.0              |       h7b6447c_0         1.9 MB  anaconda
    tensorboard-1.9.0          |   py36hf484d3e_0         3.3 MB  anaconda
    tensorflow-1.9.0           |gpu_py36h02c5d5e_1           3 KB  anaconda
    tensorflow-base-1.9.0      |gpu_py36h6ecc378_0       170.8 MB  anaconda
    tensorflow-gpu-1.9.0       |       hf154084_0           2 KB  anaconda
    termcolor-1.1.0            |           py36_1           7 KB  anaconda
    tk-8.6.8                   |       hbc83047_0         3.1 MB  anaconda
    werkzeug-0.14.1            |           py36_0         423 KB  anaconda
    wheel-0.32.3               |           py36_0          35 KB  anaconda
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:       985.7 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  _tflow_190_select  anaconda/linux-64::_tflow_190_select-0.0.1-gpu
  c-ares             anaconda/linux-64::c-ares-1.15.0-h7b6447c_1
  cudatoolkit        anaconda/linux-64::cudatoolkit-9.0-h13b8566_0
  cudnn              anaconda/linux-64::cudnn-7.1.2-cuda9.0_0
  cupti              anaconda/linux-64::cupti-9.0.176-0
  krb5               anaconda/linux-64::krb5-1.16.1-h173b8e3_7
  pip                anaconda/linux-64::pip-18.1-py36_0
  tensorflow-gpu     anaconda/linux-64::tensorflow-gpu-1.9.0-hf154084_0

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  absl-py            conda-forge/noarch::absl-py-0.1.10-py~ --> anaconda/linux-64::absl-py-0.7.0-py36_0
  ca-certificates    conda-forge::ca-certificates-2018.11.~ --> anaconda::ca-certificates-2018.12.5-0
  curl                    pkgs/main::curl-7.60.0-h84994c4_0 --> anaconda::curl-7.63.0-hbc83047_1000
  gast                                         0.2.0-py27_0 --> 0.2.2-py36_0
  grpcio             pkgs/main::grpcio-1.12.1-py27hdbcaa40~ --> anaconda::grpcio-1.16.1-py36hf8bcb03_1
  libcurl              pkgs/main::libcurl-7.60.0-h1ad7b7a_0 --> anaconda::libcurl-7.63.0-h20c2e04_1000
  libedit                 pkgs/main::libedit-3.1-heed3624_0 --> anaconda::libedit-3.1.20181209-hc058e9b_0
  markdown           conda-forge/noarch::markdown-2.6.11-p~ --> anaconda/linux-64::markdown-3.0.1-py36_0
  mkl_fft            pkgs/main::mkl_fft-1.0.6-py27hd81dba3~ --> anaconda::mkl_fft-1.0.10-py36ha843d7b_0
  ncurses                 pkgs/main::ncurses-6.0-h9df7e31_2 --> anaconda::ncurses-6.1-he6710b0_1
  openssl            conda-forge::openssl-1.0.2p-h14c3975_~ --> anaconda::openssl-1.1.1-h7b6447c_0
  protobuf           conda-forge::protobuf-3.5.2-py27hd28b~ --> anaconda::protobuf-3.5.2-py36hf484d3e_1
  python               pkgs/main::python-2.7.14-h1571d57_29 --> anaconda::python-3.6.8-h0371630_0
  setuptools            pkgs/main::setuptools-38.4.0-py27_0 --> anaconda::setuptools-40.6.3-py36_0
  six                  pkgs/main::six-1.11.0-py27h5f960f1_1 --> anaconda::six-1.12.0-py36_0
  sqlite                pkgs/main::sqlite-3.23.1-he433501_0 --> anaconda::sqlite-3.26.0-h7b6447c_0
  tensorflow           conda-forge::tensorflow-1.3.0-py27_0 --> anaconda::tensorflow-1.9.0-gpu_py36h02c5d5e_1
  tk                         pkgs/main::tk-8.6.7-hc745277_3 --> anaconda::tk-8.6.8-hbc83047_0
  wheel              pkgs/main::wheel-0.30.0-py27h2bc6bb2_1 --> anaconda::wheel-0.32.3-py36_0

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  certifi            conda-forge::certifi-2018.11.29-py27_~ --> anaconda::certifi-2018.11.29-py36_0
  git                 pkgs/main::git-2.17.0-pl526hb75a9fb_0 --> anaconda::git-2.11.1-0
  libssh2               pkgs/main::libssh2-1.8.0-h9cfc8f7_4 --> anaconda::libssh2-1.8.0-h1ba5d50_4
  mkl_random         pkgs/main::mkl_random-1.0.2-py27hd81d~ --> anaconda::mkl_random-1.0.2-py36hd81dba3_0
  numpy              pkgs/main::numpy-1.15.4-py27h7e9f1db_0 --> anaconda::numpy-1.15.4-py36h7e9f1db_0
  numpy-base         pkgs/main::numpy-base-1.15.4-py27hde5~ --> anaconda::numpy-base-1.15.4-py36hde5b4d6_0
  qt                         pkgs/main::qt-5.9.4-h4e5bff0_0 --> anaconda::qt-4.8.7-2
  tensorflow-base    pkgs/main::tensorflow-base-1.9.0-eige~ --> anaconda::tensorflow-base-1.9.0-gpu_py36h6ecc378_0
  werkzeug                pkgs/main::werkzeug-0.14.1-py27_0 --> anaconda::werkzeug-0.14.1-py36_0

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

  astor                                        0.7.1-py27_0 --> 0.7.1-py36_0
  tensorboard                         1.10.0-py27hf484d3e_0 --> 1.9.0-py36hf484d3e_0
  termcolor                                    1.1.0-py27_1 --> 1.1.0-py36_1


Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages
tensorflow-gpu-1.9.0 | 2 KB      | ########################################################################################################################################## | 100% 
absl-py-0.7.0        | 156 KB    | ########################################################################################################################################## | 100% 
six-1.12.0           | 22 KB     | ########################################################################################################################################## | 100% 
git-2.11.1           | 9.5 MB    | ########################################################################################################################################## | 100% 
_tflow_190_select-0. | 2 KB      | ########################################################################################################################################## | 100% 
setuptools-40.6.3    | 625 KB    | ########################################################################################################################################## | 100% 
c-ares-1.15.0        | 98 KB     | ########################################################################################################################################## | 100% 
cupti-9.0.176        | 1.6 MB    | ########################################################################################################################################## | 100% 
libssh2-1.8.0        | 233 KB    | ########################################################################################################################################## | 100% 
gast-0.2.2           | 138 KB    | ########################################################################################################################################## | 100% 
ncurses-6.1          | 958 KB    | ########################################################################################################################################## | 100% 
protobuf-3.5.2       | 610 KB    | ########################################################################################################################################## | 100% 
tensorflow-base-1.9. | 170.8 MB  | ########################################################################################################################################## | 100% 
ca-certificates-2018 | 123 KB    | ########################################################################################################################################## | 100% 
python-3.6.8         | 34.4 MB   | ########################################################################################################################################## | 100% 
cudatoolkit-9.0      | 340.4 MB  | ########################################################################################################################################## | 100% 
qt-4.8.7             | 34.1 MB   | ########################################################################################################################################## | 100% 
sqlite-3.26.0        | 1.9 MB    | ########################################################################################################################################## | 100% 
astor-0.7.1          | 43 KB     | ########################################################################################################################################## | 100% 
tensorboard-1.9.0    | 3.3 MB    | ########################################################################################################################################## | 100% 
mkl_fft-1.0.10       | 170 KB    | ########################################################################################################################################## | 100% 
mkl_random-1.0.2     | 407 KB    | ########################################################################################################################################## | 100% 
certifi-2018.11.29   | 146 KB    | ########################################################################################################################################## | 100% 
wheel-0.32.3         | 35 KB     | ########################################################################################################################################## | 100% 
numpy-base-1.15.4    | 4.3 MB    | ########################################################################################################################################## | 100% 
numpy-1.15.4         | 47 KB     | ########################################################################################################################################## | 100% 
curl-7.63.0          | 145 KB    | ########################################################################################################################################## | 100% 
openssl-1.1.1        | 5.0 MB    | ########################################################################################################################################## | 100% 
tk-8.6.8             | 3.1 MB    | ########################################################################################################################################## | 100% 
libedit-3.1.20181209 | 188 KB    | ########################################################################################################################################## | 100% 
markdown-3.0.1       | 107 KB    | ########################################################################################################################################## | 100% 
werkzeug-0.14.1      | 423 KB    | ########################################################################################################################################## | 100% 
krb5-1.16.1          | 1.4 MB    | ########################################################################################################################################## | 100% 
termcolor-1.1.0      | 7 KB      | ########################################################################################################################################## | 100% 
pip-18.1             | 1.8 MB    | ########################################################################################################################################## | 100% 
libcurl-7.63.0       | 550 KB    | ########################################################################################################################################## | 100% 
tensorflow-1.9.0     | 3 KB      | ########################################################################################################################################## | 100% 
grpcio-1.16.1        | 1.1 MB    | ########################################################################################################################################## | 100% 
cudnn-7.1.2          | 367.8 MB  | ########################################################################################################################################## | 100% 
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
```

(OK - I see the change to Python 3.7 now, but that's still a nasty thing to have to be careful about. Is there some way to force it to leave my Python version alone?)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Cause

**Changing Python versions without updating the `conda` package breaks Conda.** . The Python version change (2.7.14 -> 3.6.8) created a situation where the new `python` has a new `site-packages` which no longer contains a `conda` package, whereas if you only update within 2.7.x, this wouldn't be an issue.

Conda includes both a set of binaries (e.g., what you're invoking when you type `conda` in a shell) and a Python package by the same name. The Python package is necessary for Conda as a whole to function and it get's loaded whenever you try to use `conda`.

It is problematic that many packages on Anaconda seem to be triggering Python version changes, but not subsequently triggering a `conda` package update.  This sounds like something the dependency resolver is overlooking - i.e., default behavior should be to protect integrity of **base** environment where `conda` lives.

## Trying to Recover

One possible route to recovery is to temporarily use [`micromamba`](https://mamba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#micromamba) (a standalone build of `mamba`) to repair the **base** environment. You can do all the following from any directory, so maybe use a temporary one or wherever you put downloads. Please report in the comments if this works or needs adjusting!

#### Installing Micromamba

1. [Download the appropriate `micromamba`](https://mamba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#micromamba) for your platform (here we'll use the latest **linux-64** build). The actual binary will be at `bin/micromamba`:

   ```bash
   # download and unpack
   wget -qO- https://micro.mamba.pm/api/micromamba/linux-64/latest | tar -xvj bin/micromamba
   ```
2. Temporarily set `MAMBA_ROOT_PREFIX` to the base of your install. Typically this is the `anaconda3` or `miniconda3` folder; in this case, we'll use the path given by OP:

   ```
   export MAMBA_ROOT_PREFIX=/home/me/anaconda2
   ```
3. Temporarily configured the shell to add the `micromamba` command:

   ```
   eval "$(./bin/micromamba shell hook -s posix)"
   ```
4. Test that is works by checking the configuration information:

   ```
   micromamba info
   ```

   The key thing to check for is that `base environment:`  correctly identifies to where your **base** env is and shows it as `(writable)`. You should also see the `pkgs` folder in your **base** env in the `package cache:` .

#### Reinstall `conda` for the Current Python

5. (Re-)Install the `conda` package in the **base** env:

   ```
   micromamba install -n base conda
   ```

   Make sure that the build of Conda that is suggested corresponds to the version of Python currently installed. The `--force-reinstall` flag might be useful if it claims the requirement is already satisfied. Alternatively, try

   ```
   micromamba upgrade -n base conda
   ```

Try a new shell and see if `conda` is working. You don't need to keep the `micromamba` around. However, I do enthusiastically encourage users to permanently install `mamba` (see next step).

#### (Optional) Install Mamba in **base**

6. Consider also installing Mamba directly in the **base** environment. It is a compiled (fast!) alternative frontend to Conda environment management.

   ```
   micromamba install -n base mamba
   ```

   One can then use `mamba` in most places where `conda` would be used.

### Last Recourse

If all else fails you may just have to reinstall. Others have reported installing in other directories and being able to still use and access their environmentss.

## Preventions

#### Avoiding Breakage through Better Practice

First, just a general (*opinionated*) recommendation: **leverage virtual environments more**. This isn't directly solving the problem, but it will help you have a workflow that is significantly less prone to encountering such pitfalls. You shouldn't have accepted such a huge change in the first place, not to **base**. Personally, I rarely install things in **base** outside of infrastructure (emacs, jupyter-related things, conda, etc.).<sup>**1**</sup>  Software packages go into project-specific or at least development-type environments.

For example, were I doing the install shown, I would have made a new environment for it

```
mamba create -n tf36 anaconda::tensorflow-gpu python=3.6
```

or whatever Python version you actually wish to work in.

#### Direct Solution: Pinning

Conda does support package pinning, and this is the more direct way to ensure you never ruin your **base** install again by transitioning Python 2 to 3.  Namely, in the environment's `conda-meta` folder create a file, `pinned` and add the line

```
python 2.7.*
```

Note that some users have reported similar issues for 3.6 -> 3.7 transitions, so I believe including the minor version here is necessary.  See [the documentation on pinning](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#preventing-packages-from-updating-pinning).

---

<sub>[1] Note that I use [a Miniforge variant](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#miniforge) (Mambaforge), not the Anaconda installer, so I have more control over **base** from the start.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explain here, it would be greatly appreciated if you can take a look at this very similar but pending issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54758234/anaconda-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-conda

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I couldn't recover properly and actually had to remove and reinstall Anaconda from scratch. It kinda sucks that this problem can happen just by doing `conda update --all`, with no warnings whatsoever.

Comment: I would like to confirm facing the same problem for 3.6->3.7 transitions.

Comment: How is one supposed to update python versions without breaking conda then?  I tried to simply update python from 3.6->3.8 and broke my env.

Comment: @Mastiff generally, it's not recommended to upgrade a Python version in place (beyond patches). There's also almost no point to it as it triggers nearly every package to require a new build. Just create a new environment. Also, I highly discourage all users from using their **base** environment for work, so the Python version in there should never matter.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue by removing any PYTHONHOME sys PATH(s).