# I have just updated python from 3.6 to 3.7 using conda, now conda doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, conda

After updating to python3.7, conda no longer works:

```
DN0a22955d:~ harryemeric$ conda list
\Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/harryemeric/anaconda3/bin/conda", line 12, in <module>
    from conda.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'
```

This is my bash profile, I tried adding the address for 3.7 but I don't know if this is right, or really what this does. Any help much appreciated!

```
source ~/.bashrc
# Setting PATH for Python 3.4
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 3.6
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# added by Anaconda3 5.0.0 installer
export PATH="/Users/harryemeric/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does using conda to install a package change my python version and remove conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54546450/how-does-using-conda-to-install-a-package-change-my-python-version-and-remove-co) The main point is you shouldn't really use `conda` to update Python in **base** env beyond the minor version (i.e., 3.6.* in your case).

Comment: If you really need your **base** Python upgraded, then there is [an Anaconda help document on how to do this](https://support.anaconda.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2797011-updating-anaconda-to-python-3-6) (sorry, I can't find a new one for 3.7).