# Anaconda: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'

Tags: anaconda, conda

Please note this error is different than what shows up (and has answer) in stackoverflow. It is definitely not duplicated.

I have seen this error before and has been able to fix it by modifying the PATH to include conda's path like below:

```
export PATH=/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/bin:$PATH
echo $PATH
/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/home/rxie/bin
```

For unknown reason, the error pops up again here, and doesn't go away even after I started a new session.

The last command I executed was:

```
conda upgrade -c conda-forge imbalanced-learn
```

and the command completed successfully.

What's wrong with conda?

Here is the directory of Anaconda:

```
#ls -la /opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/bin/conda
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 531 Feb 18 16:29 /opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/bin/conda
```

Note I have been using root to install packages.

Any clue is appreciated.

Thank you very much.

UPDATE:
Thank you @merv, I read your answer to the other thread. Not exactly same symptom though, I indeed tried out the first step which is to `sudo pip install conda`, after that, expectedly conda still throw same error so there is no way to continue with step 2 in your answer of `conda install --revision <n-1>`

Comment: Are you sure it's not related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54546450/570918)?  There seems to be a scourge of issues related to people inadvertently updated their Python version, which is what will generate a "module not found" error.

Comment: Thank you. The problem now is conda doesn't get running at all. So any possible solution should not include running a specific conda command like in the mentioned thread of `conda install --revision <n-1>`

Comment: Did you verify that the `pip` you used was specifically the one in  `/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/lib/pythonX.X/pip`? Also, do you have multiple Pythons in that lib directory?

Comment: Thank you, yes I have multiple pythons. The one in conda is /opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/lib/python3.7, but `pip -V` gives me `pip 18.0 from /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip-18.0-py3.4.egg/pip (python 3.4)`, seems to point to python3.4?

Comment: Okay, so to follow the solution from the other question, you would run `/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/lib/python3.7/pip install conda`.

Comment: Thank you. There is no pip in that folder: `/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/lib/python3.7/pip install conda
-bash: /opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/lib/python3.7/pip: No such file or directory`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188713/discussion-between-merv-and-mdivk).

Comment: Thank you merv. Please form up an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @mdivk@merv Do we have a solution now? It also happened to me after I tried to install imbalanced-learn. I am sorry I tried to follow your chat but  did not understand. Not an expert for conda/Linux,etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does using conda to install a package change my python version and remove conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54546450/how-does-using-conda-to-install-a-package-change-my-python-version-and-remove-co)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve this problem installing the version 4.6.14 of conda as suggested on this issue [9004](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9004) before perform further installs.

`conda install conda=4.6.14`

It looks like further versions of conda are introducing this error.

Comment: Thank you for the info, though I am no longer working in that environment, your input is definitely good to people later on.

Comment: +1, I tried to fresh install miniconda but updating caused this error. The most recent conda version working for me is 4.7.12.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar problem when I was trying to install opencv, I execute following command on windows powershell:

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

The powershell gave the following error

> conda : The term 'conda' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
> the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
> At line:1 char:1
>
> - conda install -c conda-forge opencv
> - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (conda:String) [],
>   CommandNotFoundException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

So I entered the condabin directory using cd command:

```
cd C:\Users\username\anaconda3\condabin
```

and executed following command

```
.\conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

opencv got installed

So U too can navigate to condabin directory and then use .\conda instead of conda

It worked for me I hope it helps you too