# Conda ModuleNotFound after installing PyTorch

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch, conda

I've had Conda installed and working fine, but after trying to install Pytorch in my base environment, I have been getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'`.

This is the installation trace:

```
$ conda install pytorch torchvision -c pytorch
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /Users/yitianzou/anaconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - pytorch
    - torchvision


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    cffi-1.12.2                |   py36hb5b8e2f_1         213 KB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:         213 KB

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  cffi                                1.11.5-py37h6174b99_1 --> 1.12.2-py36hb5b8e2f_1
  olefile                                     0.45.1-py36_0 --> 0.46-py36_0
  pytorch                     0.4.0-py36_cuda0.0_cudnn0.0_1 --> 1.0.1-py3.6_2
  torchvision        pytorch/osx-64::torchvision-0.2.1-py3~ --> pytorch/noarch::torchvision-0.2.2-py_3

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

  mkl_fft                              1.0.6-py37hb8a8100_0 --> 1.0.6-py36hb8a8100_0
  mkl_random                           1.0.2-py37h27c97d8_0 --> 1.0.1-py36h5d10147_1
  numpy                               1.15.4-py37h6a91979_0 --> 1.15.4-py36h6a91979_0
  numpy-base                          1.15.4-py37h8a80b8c_0 --> 1.15.4-py36h8a80b8c_0
  pip                                         19.0.3-py37_0 --> 19.0.3-py36_0
  pycparser                                     2.19-py37_0 --> 2.19-py36_0
  python                                   3.7.2-haf84260_0 --> 3.6.8-haf84260_0
  setuptools                                  40.8.0-py37_0 --> 40.8.0-py36_0
  six                                         1.12.0-py37_0 --> 1.12.0-py36_0
  wheel                                       0.33.1-py37_0 --> 0.33.1-py36_0


Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages
cffi-1.12.2          | 213 KB    | ################################### | 100% 
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/yitianzou/anaconda3/bin/conda", line 12, in <module>
    from conda.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'
```

It looks like my conda path is still fine:

```
$ which conda
/Users/yitianzou/anaconda3/condabin/conda
```

And my python also looks fine:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.6.8 :: Anaconda custom (x86_64)
```

However, whenever I try to use conda I get this:

```
$ conda env list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/yitianzou/anaconda3/bin/conda", line 12, in <module>
    from conda.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'
```

Any ideas on how to approach this issue?

Comment: Check the conda path - usually it's .../anaconda3/bin/conda

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54546450/how-does-using-conda-to-install-a-package-change-my-python-version-and-remove-co/54563455#54563455)  A Conda installation is Python (minor) version-specific. By accepting an install that downgraded Python in your **base** env, you've now broken Conda.

Answer (score 0):

A late reply but may be helpful for the others facing the same problem. I have experienced the same thing and fix it by reinstalling the anaconda through installer with -u option at the same path. And after checking conda list I found I mis-install the incompatible pytroch with the current conda environment.