# Conda removed after update

Tags: conda

I wanted to install module `psutil` with conda, which made me update Python to 3.7.1. This conda update messed up my system to the point that after the  update `conda` is not recognized (so I cannot, e.g. do `conda list`). How may I safely revert to the previous state or just simply fix this nightmare?

Comment: Do you still have information about the packages the installation of `psutil` changed? Without that information it will be very difficult to figure out what happened and how to fix it.

Comment: Not sure at this point. Is there a way to check it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How does using conda to install a package change my Python version and remove conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54546450/570918) Everyone I've encountered with this problem ends up reinstalling in one form or another. One user said that installing Miniconda to a different location enabled them to use Conda again, but that sounds messy. I'd really like to see if you can get my suggested solution to work ([download the `conda` Python package](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/conda/files?version=4.6.14) and install it into the `site-packages` of the Python 3.7.1).