# conda install packages without upgrading python

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda

Sometimes you just don't want to upgrade your python version, beyond say, a minor version number at most. However many packages I wish to install with conda, fetch the most recent versions of the packages, and I get notified that it will entail upgrading my environment from python 3.6 to python 3.7.

To avoid it, I manually try specifying older versions of the packages on the conda install command, till I hit one that doesn't upgrade my python's major version.

Is there any way to let conda do this search for you, or leverage conda for choosing just the right version of a package, while specifying these or other versioning constraints over the dependencies?

Although downright breakage is not very common, it is hard to rigorously maintain a stable and predictable environment when most package installs seem to upgrade too many dependencies (some warnings come and go between versions, and some API even change between package versions, even in notable libraries).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does using conda to install a package change my python version and remove conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54546450/how-does-using-conda-to-install-a-package-change-my-python-version-and-remove-co) See specifically the solution called **package version pinning**.