# after installing packages, conda is suddenly not working

Tags: python, installation, conda, theano

I installed theano and pygpu using conda:

```
conda install theano pygpu
```

The installation seemed to finish ok, but after the installation, when I want to use conda I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/arsalan/anaconda3/bin/conda", line 7, in <module>
    from conda.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'
```

Also, I'm not able to import the packages that I had previously installed with conda. For example when I try to import pandas in python, I get the following:

```
    import pandas

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does using conda to install a package change my python version and remove conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54546450/how-does-using-conda-to-install-a-package-change-my-python-version-and-remove-co). Please check the latest transaction in `anaconda3/conda-meta/history` for if it changed the Python version. Hopefully that's not the problem because I still have yet to meet anyone who has recovered from this without reinstalling Anaconda/Miniconda.

Comment: Seems `conda` was uninstalled from the "base" environment, which indicates the Anaconda installation is totally broken.