# conda_env package is not available upon downgrading Python version to 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to create a Docker image with Conda and Python 3.6 installed. I have installed Anaconda 3 with the default Python 3.7. Then I used the following command to downgrade to Python 3.6:

```
conda install -y python=3.6
```

This results in Python 3.6 successfully installing, but when I subsequently execute `conda --version`, it gives me the error

> 'conda' module not found

I found that under `python3.6/site-packages` folder there are no Conda-related packages and instead all these packages are found under `python3.7/site-packages`.

It used to work before. Is there a way to get `conda` packaged under `python3.6` folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does using conda to install a package change my python version and remove conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54546450/how-does-using-conda-to-install-a-package-change-my-python-version-and-remove-co) Note that I just updated the section on a proper recovery procedure, so please provide feedback if it works or needs an adjustment. I think you'll want the Option 2 route I suggested, i.e., reinstalling the `conda` package for the current Python version.

Comment: Thanks merv for your reply. My issue is different. Basically i'm trying to create docker image with conda and python 3.6. So in my dockerfile i have added the command "conda instal....". Python 3.6 installed successfully but when i execute conda --version i'm getting module not found error.

Comment: If you just want a specific Python/Anaconda version in your container than why not either a) install the correct Anaconda from the start (https://repo.continuum.io/archive/) or b) use the official Docker image with the correct version (https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/anaconda/tags)?

Comment: I'm using Anaconda3-2018.12-Linux-x86_64.sh and its coming with Python 3.6 by default. I'm trying to downgrade to 3.6 but facing the above mentioned issue. I can't use the docker images from the docker hub. Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: I agree with @orangeInk - a cleaner strategy is to build up from a cleaner base (e.g., another option could be Miniconda + `conda install python=3.6 anaconda conda`. However, if you insist on the downgrade, I would try including Conda explicitly in the downgrade, e.g., `conda install -y python=3.6 conda`. As pointed out in the suggested duplicate, the reason it currently breaks is because you're changing Python without also changing `conda` to match it.

Comment: Thanks oranglnk. I tried with Anconda which has 3.6 by default and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Srikanth,
You should always try creating a new environment when you are working with some old version of any library.

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.4
```

If you want to install specific packages in this environment, you can use

```
conda install -n myenv tensorflow
```

Refer to this documentation for more information:
[docs.conda.io](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html)

Comment: Thank Joystick for your reply. I don't want to create any environments. What i need is just conda with python 3.6.