# conda solving environment failed

Tags: anaconda, miniconda

Whenever I try to install a package or update Conda, the following report is generated.

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/student/miniconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1043, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/student/miniconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 84, in _main
        exit_code = do_call(args, p)
      File "/student/miniconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 82, in do_call
        exit_code = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
      File "/student/miniconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main_update.py", line 20, in execute
        install(args, parser, 'update')
      File "/student/miniconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 280, in install
        force_reinstall=context.force_reinstall or context.force,
      File "/student/miniconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 112, in solve_for_transaction
        force_remove, force_reinstall)
      File "/student/miniconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 150, in solve_for_diff
        force_remove)
      File "/student/miniconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 245, in solve_final_state
        ssc = self._add_specs(ssc)
      File "/student/miniconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 480, in _add_specs
        self.specs_to_add, (_.to_match_spec() for _ in ssc.prefix_data.iter_records())))) or []
      File "/student/miniconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/resolve.py", line 1000, in get_conflicting_specs
        unsat_specs = {s for s in specs if not r2.find_matches_with_strict(s, scp)}
      File "/student/miniconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/resolve.py", line 1000, in <setcomp>
        unsat_specs = {s for s in specs if not r2.find_matches_with_strict(s, scp)}
      File "/student/miniconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/resolve.py", line 327, in find_matches_with_strict
        sole_source_channel_name = self._get_strict_channel(ms.name)
      File "/student/miniconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/resolve.py", line 456, in _get_strict_channel
        all_channel_names = set(prec.channel.name for prec in self.groups[package_name])
    KeyError: u'conda'

$ /student/miniconda3/bin/conda update -n root -c main conda

`conda info`

      environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
        CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=cnnenv
                CONDA_EXE=/student/miniconda3/bin/conda
             CONDA_PREFIX=/student/miniconda3/envs/cnnenv
    CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(cnnenv)
         CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/student/miniconda3/bin/python
               CONDA_ROOT=/student/miniconda3
              CONDA_SHLVL=1
                  MANPATH=/usr/man:/usr/local/man:/usr/share/man:/cs/man
                     PATH=/student/miniconda3/bin:/student/miniconda3/envs/cnnenv/
                          bin:/student/miniconda3/condabin:/student/miniconda3/bin
                          :/usr/local/cuda-9.2_cms500/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/student/
                          binfo/bin:.
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>
               WINDOWPATH=2

     active environment : cnnenv
    active env location : /student/miniconda3/envs/cnnenv
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /student/.condarc
 populated config files : /student/.condarc
          conda version : 4.7.4
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 2.7.15.final.0
       virtual packages : 
       base environment : /student/miniconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/main/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/main/noarch
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /student/miniconda3/pkgs
                          /student/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /student/miniconda3/envs
                          /student/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.7.4 requests/2.21.0 CPython/2.7.15 Linux/4.15.0-66-generic ubuntu/18.04.3 glibc/2.27
                UID:GID : 6169459:4000
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Comment: Something is strange with your Miniconda. It looks like you have Python 2.7 in **base** env, but you have `miniconda3` which implies Conda should be tied to Python 3.x. Did you try to downgrade your Python in **base** or accept a transaction that did this? Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54546450/570918

Comment: I did try to upgrade it to solve the problem