# Anaconda upgraded to Python3.8 and now is not working

Tags: python, anaconda, python-3.5, conda, python-3.8

I had Anaconda linked to python3.5, but after the pip upgrade (with conda) the version of Anaconda was also upgraded to python3.8. I need to go back to the python3.5, because I have lots of libraries already installed and configured on python3.5

Conda was also updated and it was not working, but I found how to have miniconda3 working in order to test some commands.

I don't know what to do in order to recover Anaconda linked to python3.5.
Any suggestion will be more than welcome.

Comment: if conda still works, you can attempt to rollback your update: http://blog.rtwilson.com/conda-revisions-letting-you-rollback-to-a-previous-version-of-your-environment/

Comment: The question could be improved by writing out the commands that were run instead of describing them in prose. From what I understand, you ran `conda upgrade pip` in your **base** env and it resulted in also upgrading Python to 3.8? Sounds like a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54546450/how-does-using-conda-to-install-a-package-change-my-python-version-and-remove-co/54563455#54563455 (solution is basically same suggestion as @cel, but works around broken Conda by use conda-exec binary).