# No module named 'conda' after conda update

Tags: ubuntu, conda, miniconda

I have installed miniconda3 in my ubuntu machine. When I use conda then it gives following error:

```
 File "/home/himal/miniconda3/bin/conda", line 12, in <module>
    from conda.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'
```

But  code in jupyter note book from virtual environment (miniconda3/envs/himal) works. I am facing problem install new package inside virtual environment 'himal'. How to change base environment in Ubuntu?

[image]

**EDIT**

The output of

```
$ echo ~/miniconda3/lib/python*/site-packages/conda-*
```

is

```
/home/himal/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda-4.6.1-py3.7.egg-info
```

AND

```
~/miniconda3/bin/python --version
```

is

```
Python 3.8.2
```

Python version inside virtual envs is 3.7.2. While I use jupyter notebook from Pycharm virtual envs works. But problem while using conda from terminal

Comment: Added output after EDIT @cel

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How does using conda to install a package change my python version and remove conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54546450/how-does-using-conda-to-install-a-package-change-my-python-version-and-remove-co)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here likely arose from a bug in conda. The interpreter was updated to version 3.8, but conda is still installed into the python 3.7 interpreter and thus cannot be found anymore.

First we need to find out the path to the current conda library. This can be done by following command: `echo ~/miniconda3/lib/python*/site-packages/conda-*`. We then set up two helper environment variables:

```
# path to site package with conda library
SITE_PACKAGES=/home/himal/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages
# path to current miniconda base python interpreter
PYTHON_BASE=/home/himal/miniconda3/bin/python
```

We then need to find the last working revision

```
PYTHONPATH=$SITE_PACKAGES $PYTHON_BASE -m conda list --revisions
```

Find the revision id for the last conda transaction. For me this would be transaction `2020-04-03 08:19:57  (rev 107)` the id we need is 107.

Now we can revert to the previous revision (107 - 1 = 106):

```
PYTHONPATH=$SITE_PACKAGES $PYTHON_BASE -m conda install --revision 106
```

After accepting this, conda should be back.

From here, update conda to prevent this from happening in the future:

```
conda install conda python=3.7
```

Comment: Thanks this really helped me out.
At first, I couldn't execute `PYTHONPATH=$SITE_PACKAGES $PYTHON_BASE -m conda list --revisions` because a module `pycosat` was missing. A normal `pip install pycosat` solved the problem.

Comment: That works for me, Thanks a lot.
But i don't understand why install `python=3.7` can prevent this from happening in the future.

Comment: @luoochen - actually updating conda is what prevents this in the future. `python=3.7` just prevents repeating the same misery :-)

Comment: I just had to run `conda install conda python=3.10` (which is the version I wanted and it worked).

Answer (score 0):

you have to install the newest version of Conda from here, https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual by copying the link for your system (linux in your case). then you wont run into this problem!

Answer (score 0):

I just had to run `conda install conda python=3.10` (which is the version I wanted) and it worked.