# How to copy all Conda packages from one env to the base env?

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda, anaconda3

I have an environment called `envname`, but I would like its packages to be available in the `base` environment. How can I do this without reinstalling each of them?

Answer (score 1):

### Word of Caution

Be very careful when tinkering with the **base** env. It's where the `conda` package lives and so if it breaks, the Conda installation will break. [This is a very tedious situation to recover from](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54546450/570918), so I generally recommend against using the **base** env for anything other than running `conda update -n base conda`.

That said, one should only try the following for sharing between two non-**base** envs.

---

### Copying (Linking) Packages Across Envs

One way would be to export an env, let's call it **foo**, out as a YAML:

```
conda env export -n foo > foo.yaml
```

And then ask the other env, let's call it **bar**, to attempt to install all the packages:

*Warning: Conda will attempt the following command without requesting approval!*

```
conda env update -n bar -f foo.yaml
```

Note that if the **foo** env has conflicting packages, they will all supersede whatever was in the **bar** env (if resolvable). To be cautious, you should probably do a diff first, to see what is going to get overwritten. E.g.,

```
conda env export -n bar > bar.yaml  # this is also useful as backup
diff -u bar.yaml foo.yaml
```

A major thing to check for is the `python` version. They should match up to and including the minor version (e.g., `3.6.x` and `3.6.y` are okay; `3.6` and `3.7` are not).

To err on the side of caution, one should probably manually remove any packages from the YAML that would be reversions - however, this could lead to conflicts.

The deletions will not have an effect *unless* also using the `--prune` argument (essentially that would completely overwrite **bar** with **foo**).

Hopefully all these qualifications and warnings make the point: it could be a mess. It is usually better practice to thoughtfully design a fresh env from the start.