# No module named conda in Docker

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, conda, miniconda

I am trying to create a docker image with miniconda3 intalled. Instead of using directly the [base image offered in docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/miniconda3/dockerfile), I want to start from scratch by creating my own Dockerfile and putting there the commands of the Dockerfile of the continuumio/miniconda3 image, which are:

```
FROM debian:latest

#  $ docker build . -t continuumio/miniconda3:latest -t continuumio/miniconda3:4.5.11
#  $ docker run --rm -it continuumio/miniconda3:latest /bin/bash
#  $ docker push continuumio/miniconda3:latest
#  $ docker push continuumio/miniconda3:4.5.11

ENV LANG=C.UTF-8 LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
ENV PATH /opt/conda/bin:$PATH

RUN apt-get update --fix-missing && \
    apt-get install -y wget bzip2 ca-certificates curl git && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN wget --quiet https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.5.11-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda.sh && \
    /bin/bash ~/miniconda.sh -b -p /opt/conda && \
    rm ~/miniconda.sh && \
    /opt/conda/bin/conda clean -tipsy && \
    ln -s /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh /etc/profile.d/conda.sh && \
    echo ". /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> ~/.bashrc && \
    echo "conda activate base" >> ~/.bashrc

ENV TINI_VERSION v0.16.1
ADD https://github.com/krallin/tini/releases/download/${TINI_VERSION}/tini /usr/bin/tini
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/tini

ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/bin/tini", "--" ]
CMD [ "/bin/bash" ]
```

Building and running the container works just fine. For reference, here is the output of `conda info` in the container:

```
(base) root@def48bd1ed5d:/# conda info

     active environment : base
    active env location : /opt/conda
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /root/.condarc
 populated config files : 
          conda version : 4.5.11
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.7.0.final.0
       base environment : /opt/conda  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
          package cache : /opt/conda/pkgs
                          /root/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /opt/conda/envs
                          /root/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.5.11 requests/2.19.1 CPython/3.7.0 Linux/4.4.0-187-generic debian/10 glibc/2.28
                UID:GID : 0:0
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

The problem appears whenever I try to use `conda` to install a module, for example `conda install jupyter -y`. The process starts and at some point during the installation I get this error:

```
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/bin/conda", line 7, in <module>
    from conda.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'
(base) root@def48bd1ed5d:/#
```

After this, it seems the installation is corrupeted. If I try to use the `conda` command to call for exmaple `conda info` again, I get the same error:

```
(base) root@def48bd1ed5d:/# conda info
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/bin/conda", line 7, in <module>
    from conda.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'
(base) root@def48bd1ed5d:/#
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### `miniconda3` version specified in installation line inside the Dockerfile is the not the latest one

That [Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/miniconda3/dockerfile) that you used to build local image will install `miniconda3-4.5.11` not the latest version. You can find it here:

```
...
RUN wget --quiet https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.5.11-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda.sh && \
    /bin/bash ~/miniconda.sh -b -p /opt/conda &&
...
```

And also in this way with `docker`:

```sh
$ docker build --tag miniconda3:test .
$ docker docker run -i -t miniconda3:test /bin/bash
$ docker history --no-trunc miniconda3:test | grep Miniconda3

/bin/sh -c wget --quiet https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.5.11-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda.sh && ...
```

Ok, now let's look at official `continuumio/miniconda3`:

```sh
$ docker run -i -t continuumio/miniconda3 /bin/bash
```

and then:

```sh
$ docker history --no-trunc continuumio/miniconda3 | grep Miniconda3

/bin/sh -c wget --quiet https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda.sh && ...
```

As you can see `continuumio/miniconda3` image from DockerHub installs latest `miniconda3` `4.8.2` and not the `4.5.11` version. Thus, your local image built from that `Dockerfile` will produce container with `miniconda3:4.5.11`.

### Change in `python` version breaks `conda`

Now, let's figure out why `conda` fails. First build and run:

```sh
$ docker build --tag miniconda3:test .
$ docker docker run -i -t miniconda3:test /bin/bash
```

Get some info:

```sh
(base) root@61cafd17d954:/# conda info

     active environment : base
    active env location : /opt/conda
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /root/.condarc
 populated config files : 
          conda version : 4.5.11
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.7.0.final.0
       base environment : /opt/conda  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
          package cache : /opt/conda/pkgs
                          /root/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /opt/conda/envs
                          /root/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.5.11 requests/2.19.1 CPython/3.7.0 Linux/5.4.0-48-generic debian/10 glibc/2.28
                UID:GID : 0:0
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Well, we have `conda:4.5.11` with `python:3.7.0`.

Now, we are going to install `jupyter`, for example:

```sh
(base) root@61cafd17d954:/# conda install jupyter
```

You may notice, that this installation will update `python`:

```sh
The following packages will be UPDATED:

...
    python:             3.7.0-hc3d631a_0        --> 3.8.5-h7579374_1       
...
```

If you proceed, this will update `python` and will break `conda`:

```sh
...
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/bin/conda", line 7, in <module>
    from conda.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'
```

This is quite known issue and you can find more info on this issue in [How does using conda to install a package change my python version and remove conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54563455/10749432) answer, and in official conda repo: [No module named conda.cli.main #2463](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/2463).

### Update `conda` or use `Dockerfile` for the `miniconda3:latest`

There are 3 possible solutions to this issue:

1. Edit your `Dockerfile` by replacing this line:

```sh
RUN wget --quiet https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.5.11-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda.sh && \
```

with

```sh
RUN wget --quiet https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda.sh && \
```

2. Use the latest official `Dockerfile` from `ContinuumIO`, you can find it [here](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/docker-images/blob/master/miniconda3/debian/Dockerfile).
3. Update `conda` inside container before usage:

```sh
(base) root@61cafd17d954:/# conda update conda
```

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed explanaiton and references. It definetly solved the issue.