# An uxexpected error has occured. Conda has created the above report. Upload/ Report not sent

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda, anaconda3

When I updated conda to a recent one, it started showing this long list of unsent report after every command I pass. Here is the text it shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Amit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line
1079, in call
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Amit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 8
4, in _main
exit_code = do_call(args, p)
File "C:\Users\Amit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.p
y", line 83, in do_call
return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
File "C:\Users\Amit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_update.py",
line 20, in execute
install(args, parser, 'update')
File "C:\Users\Amit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", lin
e 116, in install
if context.use_only_tar_bz2:
File "C:\Users\Amit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", li
ne 745, in use_only_tar_bz2
import conda_package_handling.api
File "C:\Users\Amit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_package_handling\api
.py", line 7, in
import tqdm as _tqdm
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tqdm'
`$ C:\Users\Amit\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py update -n base conda`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
                CONDA_EXE=C:\Users\Amit\anaconda3\condabin\..\Scripts\conda.exe
               CONDA_EXES="C:\Users\Amit\anaconda3\condabin\..\Scripts\conda.exe
"
               CONDA_ROOT=C:\Users\Amit\anaconda3
           CURL_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
                 HOMEPATH=\Users\Amit
                     PATH=C:\Users\Amit\anaconda3;C:\Users\Amit\anaconda3\Librar
y\mingw-w64\bin;
                          C:\Users\Amit\anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\Amit\
anaconda3\Librar
                          y\bin;C:\Users\Amit\anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\Amit\an
aconda3\bin;C:\W
                          indows\System32;C:\Users\Amit\anaconda3;C:\Users\Amit\
anaconda3\Librar
                          y\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\Amit\anaconda3\Library\usr\bi
n;C:\Users\Amit\
                          anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\Amit\anaconda3\Scripts;
C:\Windows\Syste
                          m32
             PSMODULEPATH=C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>

     active environment : None
       user config file : C:\Users\Amit\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\Amit\.condarc
          conda version : 4.10.3
    conda-build version : 3.21.4
         python version : 3.8.8.final.0
       virtual packages : __win=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : C:\Users\Amit\anaconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : C:\Users\Amit\anaconda3\etc\conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\Amit\anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\Amit\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\Amit\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\Amit\anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\Amit\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\Amit\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.10.3 requests/2.25.1 CPython/3.8.8 Windows/8.1
 Windows/6.3.9600
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.

Upload did not complete.
```

conda info command:

```
active environment : None
       user config file : C:\Users\Amit\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\Amit\.condarc
          conda version : 4.10.3
    conda-build version : 3.21.4
         python version : 3.8.8.final.0
       virtual packages : __win=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : C:\Users\Amit\anaconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : C:\Users\Amit\anaconda3\etc\conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\Amit\anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\Amit\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\Amit\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\Amit\anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\Amit\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\Amit\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.10.3 requests/2.25.1 CPython/3.8.8 Windows/8.1
 Windows/6.3.9600
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

conda config --show-sources command:

```
==> C:\Users\Amit\.condarc <==
channels:
  - defaults
report_errors: True
```

conda list --show-channel-urls command:

```
# packages in environment at C:\Users\Amit\anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0                    py38_0    defaults
anaconda-navigator        2.0.4                    py38_0    defaults
anyio                     2.2.0            py38haa95532_2    defaults
argon2-cffi               20.1.0           py38h2bbff1b_1    defaults
async_generator           1.10               pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
backcall                  0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
backports                 1.0                pyhd3eb1b0_2    defaults
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
backports.tempfile        1.0                pyhd3eb1b0_1    defaults
backports.weakref         1.0.post1                  py_1    defaults
beautifulsoup4            4.9.3              pyha847dfd_0    defaults
blas                      1.0                         mkl    defaults
blosc                     1.21.0               h19a0ad4_0    defaults
brotli                    1.0.9                ha925a31_2    defaults
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py38h2bbff1b_1003    defaults
bzip2                     1.0.8                he774522_0    defaults
ca-certificates           2021.4.13            haa95532_1    defaults
chardet                   4.0.0           py38haa95532_1003    defaults
charls                    2.2.0                h6c2663c_0    defaults
clyent                    1.2.2                    py38_1    defaults
colorama                  0.4.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
conda                     4.10.3           py38haa95532_0    defaults
conda-build               3.21.4           py38haa95532_0    defaults
conda-content-trust       0.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
conda-env                 2.6.0                         1    defaults
conda-package-handling    1.7.3            py38h8cc25b3_1    defaults
conda-repo-cli            1.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
conda-token               0.3.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
conda-verify              3.4.2                      py_1    defaults
console_shortcut          0.1.1                         4    defaults
cryptography              3.4.7            py38h71e12ea_0    defaults
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
entrypoints               0.3                      py38_0    defaults
filelock                  3.0.12             pyhd3eb1b0_1    defaults
freetype                  2.10.4               hd328e21_0    defaults
future                    0.18.2                   py38_1    defaults
giflib                    5.2.1                h62dcd97_0    defaults
glob2                     0.7                pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
hdf5                      1.10.4               h7ebc959_0    defaults
icc_rt                    2019.0.0             h0cc432a_1    defaults
icu                       58.2                 ha925a31_3    defaults
intel-openmp              2021.2.0           haa95532_616    defaults
ipython_genutils          0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1    defaults
ipywidgets                7.6.3              pyhd3eb1b0_1    defaults
jpeg                      9b                   hb83a4c4_2    defaults
jupyter_core              4.7.1            py38haa95532_0    defaults
jupyter_server            1.4.1            py38haa95532_0    defaults
jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2                      py_0    defaults
jupyterlab_widgets        1.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1    defaults
krb5                      1.18.2               hc04afaa_0    defaults
lerc                      2.2.1                hd77b12b_0    defaults
libaec                    1.0.4                h33f27b4_1    defaults
libarchive                3.4.2                h5e25573_0    defaults
libcurl                   7.71.1               h2a8f88b_1    defaults
libdeflate                1.7                  h2bbff1b_5    defaults
libiconv                  1.15                 h1df5818_7    defaults
liblief                   0.10.1               ha925a31_0    defaults
libpng                    1.6.37               h2a8f88b_0    defaults
libsodium                 1.0.18               h62dcd97_0    defaults
libspatialindex           1.9.3                h6c2663c_0    defaults
libssh2                   1.9.0                h7a1dbc1_1    defaults
libtiff                   4.2.0                hd0e1b90_0    defaults
libxml2                   2.9.10               hb89e7f3_3    defaults
libxslt                   1.1.34               he774522_0    defaults
libzopfli                 1.0.3                ha925a31_0    defaults
lz4-c                     1.9.3                h2bbff1b_0    defaults
lzo                       2.10                 he774522_2    defaults
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6    defaults
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7    defaults
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7    defaults
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2    defaults
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2    defaults
menuinst                  1.4.16           py38he774522_1    defaults
mistune                   0.8.4           py38he774522_1000    defaults
mkl                       2021.2.0           haa95532_296    defaults
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1    defaults
navigator-updater         0.2.1                    py38_0    defaults
nbclassic                 0.2.6              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
nbclient                  0.5.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
nbformat                  5.1.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
nest-asyncio              1.5.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
openssl                   1.1.1k               h2bbff1b_0    defaults
pandoc                    2.12                 haa95532_0    defaults
pandocfilters             1.4.3            py38haa95532_1    defaults
pickleshare               0.7.5           pyhd3eb1b0_1003    defaults
pip                       21.0.1           py38haa95532_0    defaults
powershell_shortcut       0.0.1                         3    defaults
psutil                    5.8.0            py38h2bbff1b_1    defaults
py-lief                   0.10.1           py38ha925a31_0    defaults
pycosat                   0.6.3            py38h2bbff1b_0    defaults
pycparser                 2.20                       py_2    defaults
pyopenssl                 20.0.1             pyhd3eb1b0_1    defaults
pyparsing                 2.4.7              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
pyqt                      5.9.2            py38ha925a31_4    defaults
pyrsistent                0.17.3           py38he774522_0    defaults
pysocks                   1.7.1            py38haa95532_0    defaults
python                    3.8.8                hdbf39b2_5    defaults
python-libarchive-c       2.9                pyhd3eb1b0_1    defaults
pytz                      2021.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
pywinpty                  0.5.7                    py38_0    defaults
pyyaml                    5.4.1            py38h2bbff1b_1    defaults
pyzmq                     22.3.0                   pypi_0    pypi
qt                        5.9.7            vc14h73c81de_0    defaults
ruamel_yaml               0.15.100         py38h2bbff1b_0    defaults
send2trash                1.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1    defaults
setuptools                52.0.0           py38haa95532_0    defaults
sip                       4.19.13          py38ha925a31_0    defaults
snappy                    1.1.8                h33f27b4_0    defaults
sniffio                   1.2.0            py38haa95532_1    defaults
soupsieve                 2.2.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
sqlite                    3.35.4               h2bbff1b_0    defaults
tbb                       2020.3               h74a9793_0    defaults
terminado                 0.9.4            py38haa95532_0    defaults
tk                        8.6.10               he774522_0    defaults
tornado                   6.1              py38h2bbff1b_0    defaults
traitlets                 5.0.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
vc                        14.2                 h21ff451_1    defaults
vs2015_runtime            14.27.29016          h5e58377_2    defaults
webencodings              0.5.1                    py38_1    defaults
widgetsnbextension        3.5.1                    py38_0    defaults
win_inet_pton             1.1.0            py38haa95532_0    defaults
wincertstore              0.2                      py38_0    defaults
winpty                    0.4.3                         4    defaults
xmltodict                 0.12.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
xz                        5.2.5                h62dcd97_0    defaults
yaml                      0.2.5                he774522_0    defaults
zeromq                    4.3.3                ha925a31_3    defaults
zfp                       0.5.5                hd77b12b_6    defaults
zlib                      1.2.11               h62dcd97_4    defaults
zstd                      1.4.5                h04227a9_0    defaults
```

I am a anaconda beginner [Not a python beginner]

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "unsent report" - I could spot `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tqdm'` in your code however. Is that the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem in tqdm package, if you look output

```
 conda list --show-channel-urls
```

tqdm package missed. Try :

```
conda install -c conda-forge tqdm
```

and restart your python.

Happy Coding !

Answer (score 0):

Somehow `tqdm` got removed or failed to install. You'll need to reinstall it. Since Conda is broken and it is a pure Python package, the simplest procedure is probably

```bash
pip install tqdm
```

Otherwise, there are ways to recover a broken installation with a standalone copy of Conda, [as described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54563455/570918). If you go that route, rather than reverting, just use the standalone Conda to run:

```bash
conda.exe install -n base tqdm
```