# conda error trying to install scikitlearn now I can't do anything

Tags: conda

I was trying to install scikit-learn.  And recieved some errors, see below.
Now I can't do anything on conda.  I tried > conda list > conda update and for each of them recieved the same error message.  Posted second.

```
conda install -c anaconda scikit-learn
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.6.11
  latest version: 4.9.0

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base conda


## Package Plan ##
      environment location: /Users/alisonwaller/miniconda3
    
      added / updated specs:
        - scikit-learn
    
    
    The following packages will be downloaded:
    
        package                    |            build
        ---------------------------|-----------------
        blas-1.0                   |              mkl           5 KB  anaconda
        cffi-1.14.0                |   py36hb5b8e2f_0         218 KB  anaconda
        cryptography-3.3           |   py36hbcfaee0_0         613 KB
        curl-7.71.1                |       hb0a8c7a_1         143 KB  anaconda
        expat-2.2.10               |       hb1e8313_2         127 KB  anaconda
        gdbm-1.18                  |       h8a0c380_2         131 KB  conda-forge
        htslib-1.11                |       h422799e_2         1.5 MB  bioconda
        intel-openmp-2020.2        |              258         1.2 MB  anaconda
        joblib-0.17.0              |             py_0         205 KB  anaconda
        krb5-1.18.2                |       h75d18d8_0         1.2 MB  anaconda
        libblas-3.9.0              |1_h508aa58_netlib         194 KB  conda-forge
        libcblas-3.9.0             |5_h0661a58_netlib          49 KB  conda-forge
        libcurl-7.71.1             |       h8a08a2b_1         304 KB  anaconda
        libffi-3.2.1               |    h0a44026_1007          46 KB  anaconda
        liblapack-3.9.0            |5_h0661a58_netlib         2.8 MB  conda-forge
        libnghttp2-1.41.0          |       h7580e61_2         862 KB  anaconda
        libopenblas-0.3.3          |       hdc02c5d_3         8.4 MB  anaconda
        llvm-openmp-8.0.1          |       h770b8ee_0         253 KB  conda-forge
        mkl-2019.4                 |              233       155.2 MB  anaconda
        mkl-service-2.3.0          |   py36hfbe908c_0         188 KB  anaconda
        mkl_fft-1.2.0              |   py36hc64f4ea_0         162 KB  anaconda
        mkl_random-1.1.1           |   py36h959d312_0         334 KB  anaconda
        numpy-1.19.1               |   py36h3b9f5b6_0          20 KB  anaconda
        numpy-base-1.19.1          |   py36hcfb5961_0         5.1 MB  anaconda
        openssl-1.1.1h             |       haf1e3a3_0         3.4 MB  anaconda
        pypy3.6-7.3.2              |       h9f31681_2        26.0 MB  conda-forge
        python-3.6.9               |        3_73_pypy           5 KB  conda-forge
        python_abi-3.6             |    2_pypy36_pp73           4 KB  conda-forge
        scikit-learn-0.22.1        |   py36h27c97d8_0         6.3 MB  anaconda
        scipy-1.2.0                |   py36h1410ff5_0        15.8 MB  anaconda
        ------------------------------------------------------------
                                               Total:       230.7 MB
    
    The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:
    
      blas               anaconda/osx-64::blas-1.0-mkl
      curl               anaconda/osx-64::curl-7.71.1-hb0a8c7a_1
      expat              anaconda/osx-64::expat-2.2.10-hb1e8313_2
      gdbm               conda-forge/osx-64::gdbm-1.18-h8a0c380_2
      intel-openmp       anaconda/osx-64::intel-openmp-2020.2-258
      joblib             anaconda/noarch::joblib-0.17.0-py_0
      mkl                anaconda/osx-64::mkl-2019.4-233
      mkl-service        anaconda/osx-64::mkl-service-2.3.0-py36hfbe908c_0
      mkl_fft            anaconda/osx-64::mkl_fft-1.2.0-py36hc64f4ea_0
      mkl_random         anaconda/osx-64::mkl_random-1.1.1-py36h959d312_0
      numpy-base         anaconda/osx-64::numpy-base-1.19.1-py36hcfb5961_0
      pypy3.6            conda-forge/osx-64::pypy3.6-7.3.2-h9f31681_2
      scikit-learn       anaconda/osx-64::scikit-learn-0.22.1-py36h27c97d8_0
      scipy              anaconda/osx-64::scipy-1.2.0-py36h1410ff5_0
    
    The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:
    
      cffi                pkgs/main::cffi-1.14.6-py36h2125817_0 --> anaconda::cffi-1.14.0-py36hb5b8e2f_0
      cryptography       conda-forge::cryptography-35.0.0-py36~ --> pkgs/main::cryptography-3.3-py36hbcfaee0_0
      krb5                    pkgs/main::krb5-1.19.2-hcd88c3b_0 --> anaconda::krb5-1.18.2-h75d18d8_0
      libcurl              pkgs/main::libcurl-7.80.0-h6dfd666_0 --> anaconda::libcurl-7.71.1-h8a08a2b_1
      libffi                   pkgs/main::libffi-3.3-hb1e8313_2 --> anaconda::libffi-3.2.1-h0a44026_1007
      libnghttp2         pkgs/main::libnghttp2-1.46.0-ha29bfda~ --> anaconda::libnghttp2-1.41.0-h7580e61_2
      libopenblas        conda-forge::libopenblas-0.3.18-openm~ --> anaconda::libopenblas-0.3.3-hdc02c5d_3
      llvm-openmp        pkgs/main::llvm-openmp-12.0.0-h0dcd29~ --> conda-forge::llvm-openmp-8.0.1-h770b8ee_0
      numpy              conda-forge::numpy-1.19.5-py36h08b5fd~ --> anaconda::numpy-1.19.1-py36h3b9f5b6_0
      openssl              pkgs/main::openssl-1.1.1m-hca72f7f_0 --> anaconda::openssl-1.1.1h-haf1e3a3_0
      python                pkgs/main::python-3.6.13-h88f2d9e_0 --> conda-forge::python-3.6.9-3_73_pypy
    
    The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
    
      bcftools                                  1.14-hc2ba8ff_1 --> 1.8-h4da6232_3
      htslib                                    1.14-hc38c3fb_0 --> 1.11-h422799e_2
      libblas                           3.9.0-13_osx64_openblas --> 3.9.0-1_h508aa58_netlib
      libcblas                          3.9.0-13_osx64_openblas --> 3.9.0-5_h0661a58_netlib
      liblapack                         3.9.0-13_osx64_openblas --> 3.9.0-5_h0661a58_netlib
      python_abi                                    3.6-2_cp36m --> 3.6-2_pypy36_pp73
    
    
    Proceed ([y]/n)? y
    
    
    Downloading and Extracting Packages
    python_abi-3.6       | 4 KB      | ############################################################################################# | 100% 
    curl-7.71.1          | 143 KB    | ############################################################################################# | 100% 
    expat-2.2.10         | 127 KB    | ############################################################################################# | 100% 
    llvm-openmp-8.0.1    | 253 KB    | ############################################################################################# | 100% 
    krb5-1.18.2          | 1.2 MB    | ############################################################################################# | 100% 
    libblas-3.9.0        | 194 KB    | ############################################################################################# | 100% 
    htslib-1.11          | 1.5 MB    | ############################################################################################# | 100% 
    gdbm-1.18            | 131 KB    | ############################################################################################# | 100% 
    scikit-learn-0.22.1  | 6.3 MB    | ############################################################################################# | 100% 
    pypy3.6-7.3.2        | 26.0 MB   | ############################################################################################# | 100% 
    blas-1.0             | 5 KB      | ############################################################################################# | 100% 
    mkl_fft-1.2.0        | 162 KB    | ############################################################################################# | 100% 
    mkl-service-2.3.0    | 188 KB    | ############################################################################################# | 100% 
    intel-openmp-2020.2  | 1.2 MB    | ############################################################################################# | 100% 
    cffi-1.14.0          | 218 KB    | ############################################################################################# | 100% 
    openssl-1.1.1h       | 3.4 MB    | ############################################################################################# | 100% 
    numpy-base-1.19.1    | 5.1 MB    | ############################################################################################# | 100% 
    libopenblas-0.3.3    | 8.4 MB    | ############################################################################################# | 100% 
    libcurl-7.71.1       | 304 KB    | ############################################################################################# | 100% 
    joblib-0.17.0        | 205 KB    | ############################################################################################# | 100% 
    cryptography-3.3     | 613 KB    | ############################################################################################# | 100% 
    libcblas-3.9.0       | 49 KB     | ############################################################################################# | 100% 
    numpy-1.19.1         | 20 KB     | ############################################################################################# | 100% 
    liblapack-3.9.0      | 2.8 MB    | ############################################################################################# | 100% 
    libnghttp2-1.41.0    | 862 KB    | ############################################################################################# | 100% 
    scipy-1.2.0          | 15.8 MB   | ############################################################################################# | 100% 
    libffi-3.2.1         | 46 KB     | ############################################################################################# | 100% 
    python-3.6.9         | 5 KB      | ############################################################################################# | 100% 
    mkl-2019.4           | 155.2 MB  | ############################################################################################# | 100% 
    mkl_random-1.1.1     | 334 KB    | ############################################################################################# | 100% 
    Preparing transaction: done
    Verifying transaction: done
    Executing transaction: done
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/alisonwaller/miniconda3/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 137, in main
        from ..activate import main as activator_main
      File "/Users/alisonwaller/miniconda3/site-packages/conda/activate.py", line 21, in <module>
        from .base.context import ROOT_ENV_NAME, context, locate_prefix_by_name
      File "/Users/alisonwaller/miniconda3/site-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 15, in <module>
        from .constants import (APP_NAME, ChannelPriority, DEFAULTS_CHANNEL_NAME,
      File "/Users/alisonwaller/miniconda3/site-packages/conda/base/constants.py", line 23, in <module>
        machine_bits = 8 * tuple.__itemsize__
    AttributeError: type object 'tuple' has no attribute '__itemsize__'
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/alisonwaller/miniconda3/bin/conda", line 13, in <module>
        sys.exit(main())
      File "/Users/alisonwaller/miniconda3/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 146, in main
        from ..exceptions import ExceptionHandler
      File "/Users/alisonwaller/miniconda3/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 22, in <module>
        from .base.constants import COMPATIBLE_SHELLS, PathConflict, SafetyChecks
      File "/Users/alisonwaller/miniconda3/site-packages/conda/base/constants.py", line 23, in <module>
        machine_bits = 8 * tuple.__itemsize__
    AttributeError: type object 'tuple' has no attribute '__itemsize__'
```

Now here is the error I get when I try conda list or conda update.  I have read through what I thought were similar post but many of them were resolved through some sort of updating or installing new versions of specific libraries, but I can't seem to do anything with conda now.

Any help appreciated

```
conda update --all
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alisonwaller/miniconda3/bin/conda", line 13, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/alisonwaller/miniconda3/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 149, in main
    from ..exceptions import conda_exception_handler
  File "/Users/alisonwaller/miniconda3/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .base.constants import COMPATIBLE_SHELLS, PathConflict, SafetyChecks
  File "/Users/alisonwaller/miniconda3/site-packages/conda/base/constants.py", line 23, in <module>
    machine_bits = 8 * tuple.__itemsize__
AttributeError: type object 'tuple' has no attribute '__itemsize__'
```

Comment: This seems related, but not an identical cause: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54563455/570918 Not exactly sure what happened here, but possibly has to do with switching from regular Python (sourced from the `defaults` channel) to a PyPy build of Python (from `conda-forge`). Generally, one shouldn't be mixing channels, nor even using the **base** environment for work.

Answer (score 0):

So I resolved in by:

- uninstalling miniconda
- Reinstalling miniconda
- adjust the PATH in
  my bash_profile file
- restart the terminal

Comment: Strongly recommend against "*adjust the PATH in my bash_profile file*". See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55526573/570918