# Update (mini)conda in ubuntu terminal works fine, but when i try the same with ansible on the localhost i get an error, does somebody know a solution?

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, anaconda, conda, miniconda

If i run following command in the ubuntu terminal it gets excecuted with no errors:

```
/opt/miniconda3/bin/conda update conda -y
```

But when i try the same command with Ansible on my localhost(so the same ubuntu) i get a big error.
Ansible code:

```
- name: conda - update
  become: True
  shell: /opt/miniconda3/bin/conda update conda -y
  args:
      executable: /bin/bash
```

I also tried it without the arguments but i get the same error. Does someone know how to fix  that error or another way to update (mini)conda with Ansible?

The error is the following:

> TASK [conda : conda - update] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "/opt/miniconda3/bin/conda update conda -y", "delta": "0:01:23.130438", "end": "2022-04-27 01:20:14.709342", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2022-04-27 01:18:51.578904", "stderr": "\rca-certificates-2022 |  129 KB |            |   0% \rca-certificates-2022 |  129 KB | 9          |   9% \rca-certificates-2022 |  129 KB | ########## | 100% \n\rsetuptools-61.2.0    |  1.3 MB |            |   0% \rsetuptools-61.2.0    |  1.3 MB |            |   1% \rsetuptools-61.2.0    |  1.3 MB | ####5      |  46% \rsetuptools-61.2.0    |  1.3 MB | #######9   |  80% \rsetuptools-61.2.0    |  1.3 MB | #########4 |  94% \rsetuptools-61.2.0    |  1.3 MB | ########## | 100% \n\rconda-package-handli |  954 KB |            |   0% \rconda-package-handli |  954 KB | 1          |   1% \rconda-package-handli |  954 KB | #1         |  11% \rconda-package-handli |  954 KB | ##3        |  24% \rconda-package-handli |  954 KB | ###9       |  39% \rconda-package-handli |  954 KB | #####9     |  59% \rconda-package-handli |  954 KB | #######8   |  79% \rconda-package-handli |  954 KB | #########2 |  92% \rconda-package-handli |  954 KB | ########## | 100% \n\rurllib3-1.26.9       |  176 KB |            |   0% \rurllib3-1.26.9       |  176 KB | 6          |   7% \rurllib3-1.26.9       |  176 KB | ########## | 100% \nERROR conda.core.link:_execute(502): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::charset-normalizer-2.0.4-pyhd3eb1b0_0'.\nAssertionError()\nAttempting to roll back.\n\n\nAssertionError()\nAssertionError()", "stderr_lines": ["", "ca-certificates-2022 |  129 KB |            |   0% ", "ca-certificates-2022 |  129 KB | 9          |   9% ", "ca-certificates-2022 |  129 KB | ########## | 100% ", "", "setuptools-61.2.0    |  1.3 MB |            |   0% ", "setuptools-61.2.0    |  1.3 MB |            |   1% ", "setuptools-61.2.0    |  1.3 MB | ####5      |  46% ", "setuptools-61.2.0    |  1.3 MB | #######9   |  80% ", "setuptools-61.2.0    |  1.3 MB | #########4 |  94% ", "setuptools-61.2.0    |  1.3 MB | ########## | 100% ", "", "conda-package-handli |  954 KB |            |   0% ", "conda-package-handli |  954 KB | 1          |   1% ", "conda-package-handli |  954 KB | #1         |  11% ", "conda-package-handli |  954 KB | ##3        |  24% ", "conda-package-handli |  954 KB | ###9       |  39% ", "conda-package-handli |  954 KB | #####9     |  59% ", "conda-package-handli |  954 KB | #######8   |  79% ", "conda-package-handli |  954 KB | #########2 |  92% ", "conda-package-handli |  954 KB | ########## | 100% ", "", "urllib3-1.26.9       |  176 KB |            |   0% ", "urllib3-1.26.9       |  176 KB | 6          |   7% ", "urllib3-1.26.9       |  176 KB | ########## | 100% ", "ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(502): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::charset-normalizer-2.0.4-pyhd3eb1b0_0'.", "AssertionError()", "Attempting to roll back.", "", "", "AssertionError()", "AssertionError()"], "stdout": "Solving environment: ...working... done\n\n## Package Plan ##\n\n  environment location: /opt/miniconda3\n\n  added / updated specs: \n    - conda\n\n\nThe following packages will be downloaded:\n\n    package                    |            build\n    ---------------------------|-----------------\n    ca-certificates-2022.3.29  |       h06a4308_1         129 KB\n    setuptools-61.2.0          |   py37h06a4308_0         1.3 MB\n    conda-package-handling-1.8.1|   py37h7f8727e_0         954 KB\n    urllib3-1.26.9             |   py37h06a4308_0         176 KB\n    ------------------------------------------------------------\n                                           Total:         2.5 MB\n\nThe following packages will be UPDATED:\n\n    asn1crypto:             0.24.0-py36_0           --> 1.4.0-py_0              \n    brotlipy:               0.7.0-py39h27cfd23_1003 --> 0.7.0-py37h27cfd23_1003 \n    ca-certificates:        2018.03.07-0            --> 2022.3.29-h06a4308_1    \n    certifi:                2018.4.16-py36_0        --> 2021.10.8-py37h06a4308_2\n    cffi:                   1.11.5-py36h9745a5d_0   --> 1.15.0-py37h7f8727e_0   \n    chardet:                3.0.4-py36h0f667ec_1    --> 4.0.0-py37h06a4308_1003 \n    charset-normalizer:     2.0.4-pyhd3eb1b0_0      --> 2.0.4-pyhd3eb1b0_0      \n    colorama:               0.4.4-pyhd3eb1b0_0      --> 0.4.4-pyhd3eb1b0_0      \n    conda:                  4.5.4-py36_0            --> 4.12.0-py37h06a4308_0   \n    conda-package-handling: 1.8.0-py39h7f8727e_0    --> 1.8.1-py37h7f8727e_0    \n    cryptography:           2.2.2-py36h14c3975_0    --> 36.0.0-py37h9ce1e76_0   \n    idna:                   2.6-py36h82fb2a8_1      --> 3.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0        \n    libgcc-ng:              7.2.0-hdf63c60_3        --> 9.1.0-hdf63c60_0        \n    libstdcxx-ng:           7.2.0-hdf63c60_3        --> 9.1.0-hdf63c60_0        \n    openssl:                1.0.2o-h20670df_0       --> 1.1.1n-h7f8727e_0       \n    pip:                    10.0.1-py36_0           --> 21.2.2-py37h06a4308_0   \n    pycosat:                0.6.3-py36h0a5515d_0    --> 0.6.3-py37h27cfd23_0    \n    pycparser:              2.18-py36hf9f622e_1     --> 2.21-pyhd3eb1b0_0       \n    pyopenssl:              18.0.0-py36_0           --> 22.0.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0     \n    pysocks:                1.6.8-py36_0            --> 1.7.1-py37_1            \n    python:                 3.6.5-hc3d631a_2        --> 3.7.2-h0371630_0        \n    requests:               2.18.4-py36he2e5f8d_1   --> 2.27.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0     \n    ruamel_yaml:            0.15.37-py36h14c3975_2  --> 0.15.87-py37h7b6447c_0  \n    setuptools:             39.2.0-py36_0           --> 61.2.0-py37h06a4308_0   \n    six:                    1.11.0-py36h372c433_1   --> 1.16.0-pyhd3eb1b0_1     \n    sqlite:                 3.23.1-he433501_0       --> 3.26.0-h7b6447c_0       \n    tk:                     8.6.7-hc745277_3        --> 8.6.11-h1ccaba5_0       \n    tqdm:                   4.63.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0     --> 4.63.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0     \n    urllib3:                1.22-py36hbe7ace6_0     --> 1.26.9-py37h06a4308_0   \n    wheel:                  0.31.1-py36_0           --> 0.37.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0     \n\n\nDownloading and Extracting Packages\nPreparing transaction: ...working... done\nVerifying transaction: ...working... done\nExecuting transaction: ...working... failed\nRolling back transaction: ...working... done", "stdout_lines": ["Solving environment: ...working... done", "", "## Package Plan ##", "", "  environment location: /opt/miniconda3", "", "  added / updated specs: ", "    - conda", "", "", "The following packages will be downloaded:", "", "    package                    |            build", "    ---------------------------|-----------------", "    ca-certificates-2022.3.29  |       h06a4308_1         129 KB", "    setuptools-61.2.0          |   py37h06a4308_0         1.3 MB", "    conda-package-handling-1.8.1|   py37h7f8727e_0         954 KB", "    urllib3-1.26.9             |   py37h06a4308_0         176 KB", "    ------------------------------------------------------------", "                                           Total:         2.5 MB", "", "The following packages will be UPDATED:", "", "    asn1crypto:             0.24.0-py36_0           --> 1.4.0-py_0              ", "    brotlipy:               0.7.0-py39h27cfd23_1003 --> 0.7.0-py37h27cfd23_1003 ", "    ca-certificates:        2018.03.07-0            --> 2022.3.29-h06a4308_1    ", "    certifi:                2018.4.16-py36_0        --> 2021.10.8-py37h06a4308_2", "    cffi:                   1.11.5-py36h9745a5d_0   --> 1.15.0-py37h7f8727e_0   ", "    chardet:                3.0.4-py36h0f667ec_1    --> 4.0.0-py37h06a4308_1003 ", "    charset-normalizer:     2.0.4-pyhd3eb1b0_0      --> 2.0.4-pyhd3eb1b0_0      ", "    colorama:               0.4.4-pyhd3eb1b0_0      --> 0.4.4-pyhd3eb1b0_0      ", "    conda:                  4.5.4-py36_0            --> 4.12.0-py37h06a4308_0   ", "    conda-package-handling: 1.8.0-py39h7f8727e_0    --> 1.8.1-py37h7f8727e_0    ", "    cryptography:           2.2.2-py36h14c3975_0    --> 36.0.0-py37h9ce1e76_0   ", "    idna:                   2.6-py36h82fb2a8_1      --> 3.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0        ", "    libgcc-ng:              7.2.0-hdf63c60_3        --> 9.1.0-hdf63c60_0        ", "    libstdcxx-ng:           7.2.0-hdf63c60_3        --> 9.1.0-hdf63c60_0        ", "    openssl:                1.0.2o-h20670df_0       --> 1.1.1n-h7f8727e_0       ", "    pip:                    10.0.1-py36_0           --> 21.2.2-py37h06a4308_0   ", "    pycosat:                0.6.3-py36h0a5515d_0    --> 0.6.3-py37h27cfd23_0    ", "    pycparser:              2.18-py36hf9f622e_1     --> 2.21-pyhd3eb1b0_0       ", "    pyopenssl:              18.0.0-py36_0           --> 22.0.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0     ", "    pysocks:                1.6.8-py36_0            --> 1.7.1-py37_1            ", "    python:                 3.6.5-hc3d631a_2        --> 3.7.2-h0371630_0        ", "    requests:               2.18.4-py36he2e5f8d_1   --> 2.27.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0     ", "    ruamel_yaml:            0.15.37-py36h14c3975_2  --> 0.15.87-py37h7b6447c_0  ", "    setuptools:             39.2.0-py36_0           --> 61.2.0-py37h06a4308_0   ", "    six:                    1.11.0-py36h372c433_1   --> 1.16.0-pyhd3eb1b0_1     ", "    sqlite:                 3.23.1-he433501_0       --> 3.26.0-h7b6447c_0       ", "    tk:                     8.6.7-hc745277_3        --> 8.6.11-h1ccaba5_0       ", "    tqdm:                   4.63.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0     --> 4.63.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0     ", "    urllib3:                1.22-py36hbe7ace6_0     --> 1.26.9-py37h06a4308_0   ", "    wheel:                  0.31.1-py36_0           --> 0.37.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0     ", "", "", "Downloading and Extracting Packages", "Preparing transaction: ...working... done", "Verifying transaction: ...working... done", "Executing transaction: ...working... failed", "Rolling back transaction: ...working... done"]}

Comment: Not sure the issue, but that looks like a high-risk transaction. It's trying to upgrade Python and one really should never `-y` a change that upgrades Python in-place in the **base** environment. That's how users end up at https://stackoverflow.com/q/54546450/570918. Consider either interactively running the upgrade or pinning the Python version - though v3.6 is getting dated and may not support newer Conda versions.

Comment: Separately, are you sure this is targeting the same Conda installation? It might be useful to add a `--name base` argument to the `conda update` command, to explicitly declare what environment it's supposed to be targeting.

Comment: Not sure this is the issue but just in case: Ansible uses a non-login non-interactive shell. It does not read any init file like `.login`, `.bashrc`... if your command is expecting an env var defined in your user's login environment to work correctly, you have to define it or source the given init file yourself.

Comment: @Zeitounator good point - yes, that is certainly the case with typical Conda installations, which create shell functions and activate default (**base**) environment in such initialization files.

Comment: @merv i tried both your options but both didnt work. But thank your for the effort in helping me.

Comment: @Zeitounator And how can i define that?  Can you give an example or show me how? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Quick and dirty: `shell: source $HOME/.bashrc && <rest of your command>`. Else see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html