# conda and mamba were broken (segmentation fault) after installing "conda install -c asmeurer glibc"

Tags: python, conda, ubuntu-20.04, mamba

I am a Thai microbiologist try to use command line.
I installed "Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows" then bowtie2 by conda:

```
conda install -c bioconda bowtie2
```

and then check version of the bowtie2. it is 2.2.5 but I need 2.4.5. the con labels is weird like this https://github.com/BenLangmead/bowtie2/issues/397 but that is not the main point.

I try everything on the Internet.
finally, it worked on MacOX somehow.

but for "Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows" because bowtie2 is not compatible with current GLIBC and glibc after I ran:

```
conda install -c asmeurer glibc
```

after this glibc was installed, conda return nothing, mamba return "segmentation fault" and

the bowtie2 was upgraded to 2.3.5.1. (the scenario is like this https://www.biostars.org/p/433973/). It is like I broke the conda and mamba.
Do I need to uninstall "Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows"? or can I just delete whole miniconda3 folder and then re-install it?

thank you in advance

Chooseel

Answer (score 1):

Broken Conda environments can be repaired externally using Micromamba (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54563455/570918)). No need to uninstall stuff. But if you want to start clean, it should be sufficient to reinstall Conda.

Please be aware that users generally will have a better experience not working from the **base** environment. Instead, create dedicated environments for the various tasks/projects. That is, use

```bash
mamba create -n bowtie -c conda-forge -c bioconda bowtie2
```

Also, mixing channels can lead to issues. [Bioconda has very explicit requirements in channel priority](https://bioconda.github.io/index.html#usage):

```yaml
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults
```

Comment: I followed your steps but it said permission denied to install micromamba so I decided to reinstall UBUNTU20.04, conda, mamba, then `mamba create -n bowtie -c conda-forge -c bioconda bowtie2` it worked well. I successfully installed bowtie2 2.4.5. million thanks!