# Conda deleted itself during package installation error: how to restore it?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

During package installation on my Windows, there was an error, during which `conda` (most probably) deleted itself. Now, `conda` command is not present on my Windows.

The main error is:

```
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(733):
An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::conda-22.11.0-py39haa95532_1'
```

**Question.** How can I restore `conda` command without (deleting and) reinstalling all Anaconda?
I do not want t lose all installed packages, environments, etc. and reinstall everything. Is there a solution to this?

**Details:**

The result of OCR tool (I could not just copy-paste):

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32> conda install -c conda-forge textblob 

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done 
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

environment location: C:\Users\user\anaconda3

added / updated specs:
- textblob

The following packages will be downloaded:
package                     |   build   
----------------------------|---------------
conda-22.11.0               |   py39haa9SS32_1  932 KB  
openssl-l.l.ls              |   hcfcfb64_1      5.1 MB  conda-forge
ruamel.yaml-0.16.12         |   py39h2bbfflb_3  173 KB  
ruamel.yaml.clib-0.2.7      |   py39ha55989b_0  111 KB  conda-forge
------------------------------------------------------
                                        Total:  6.3 MB  

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

ruamel.yaml       pkgs/main/win-64::ruamel.yaml-0.16.12-py39h2bbfflb_3 None
ruamel.yaml.clib  conda-forge/win-64::ruamel.yaml.clib-0.2.7-py39ha55989b_0 None 
textblob          conda-forge/noarch::textblob-0.15.3-py_0 None

The following packages will be UPDATED:

conda   conda-forge::conda-22.9.0-py39hcbf530- --> pkgs/main::conda-22.11.0-py39haa95532_l None
openssl l.l.ls-hcfcfb64_0 --> 1.1.ls-hcfcfb64_l None

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Downloading and Extracting Packages
openssl-l.l.ls       |  5.1 MB  |
ruamel.yaml-0.16.12  |  173 KB
conda-22.11.0        |  932 KB
ruamel.yaml.clib-0.2 |  111 KB  |

Preparing transaction:  done
Verifying transaction:  done
Executing transaction:  done

ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(733): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::conda-22.11.0-py39haa95532_1'.
Rolling back transaction: done

CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. 
C:\Users\user\anaconda3\.condatmp\0d55d647-3842-4S31-a301-4bedl75b9998 
Running 'conda clean --packages' may resolve your problem.
()
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: ’C:\\Users\\user\\anaconda3\\conda-meta\\openssl-l.l.ls-hcfcfb64_0.json’
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: ’C:\\Users\\user\\anaconda3\\conda-meta\\conda-22.9.0-py39hcbf5309_2.json’

The batch file cannot be found.
The batch file cannot be found.
```

Comment: I have some directions for operating on broken Conda installations using Micromamba in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54563455/570918). Maybe duplicate?