# Conda functions in terminal (Mac) won't work: KeyError('pkgs_dirs')

Tags: python, terminal, anaconda, conda, keyerror

I cannot run Conda in Terminal (Mac) or many of its commands. Only `conda activate <env>` or `conda deactivate` run that I know of, and I can run Jupyter from my chosen environment thankfully. Otherwise I get the following error:

> conda info could not be constructed. KeyError('pkgs_dirs')

I'm at a complete loss. Should I uninstall Anaconda and reinstall it? However, I cannot use any uninstall commands from Conda—a catch-22.

Here is the complete error report:

```python
ERROR REPORT 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1118, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 57, in main_subshell
        p = generate_parser()
      File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 41, in generate_parser
        description='conda is a tool for managing and deploying applications,'
      File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 117, in __init__
        self._subcommands = context.plugin_manager.get_hook_results("subcommands")
      File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 421, in plugin_manager
        from ..plugins.manager import get_plugin_manager
      File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/plugins/manager.py", line 9, in <module>
        from . import solvers, virtual_packages
      File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/plugins/virtual_packages/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
        from . import archspec, cuda, linux, osx, windows
      File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/plugins/virtual_packages/cuda.py", line 3, in <module>
        import ctypes
      File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
        from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
    ImportError: dlopen(/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: @rpath/libffi.6.dylib
      Referenced from: <66269FD6-56F9-32A5-8A25-F986023901A1> /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-37m-darwin.so
      Reason: tried: '/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d698b2ce-b4b9-4fb4-6268-e633fba1b324/volume/python_1565725718142/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d698b2ce-b4b9-4fb4-6268-e633fba1b324/volume/python_1565725718142/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d698b2ce-b4b9-4fb4-6268-e633fba1b324/volume/python_1565725718142/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d698b2ce-b4b9-4fb4-6268-e633fba1b324/volume/python_1565725718142/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d698b2ce-b4b9-4fb4-6268-e633fba1b324/volume/python_1565725718142/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d698b2ce-b4b9-4fb4-6268-e633fba1b324/volume/python_1565725718142/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/../../libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d698b2ce-b4b9-4fb4-6268-e633fba1b324/volume/python_1565725718142/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d698b2ce-b4b9-4fb4-6268-e633fba1b324/volume/python_1565725718142/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d698b2ce-b4b9-4fb4-6268-e633fba1b324/volume/python_1565725718142/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d698b2ce-b4b9-4fb4-6268-e633fba1b324/volume/python_1565725718142/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d698b2ce-b4b9-4fb4-6268-e633fba1b324/volume/python_1565725718142/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d698b2ce-b4b9-4fb4-6268-e633fba1b324/volume/python_1565725718142/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/../../libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d698b2ce-b4b9-4fb4-6268-e633fba1b324/volume/python_1565725718142/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d698b2ce-b4b9-4fb4-6268-e633fba1b324/volume/python_1565725718142/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d698b2ce-b4b9-4fb4-6268-e633fba1b324/volume/python_1565725718142/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d698b2ce-b4b9-4fb4-6268-e633fba1b324/volume/python_1565725718142/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d698b2ce-b4b9-4fb4-6268-e633fba1b324/volume/python_1565725718142/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d698b2ce-b4b9-4fb4-6268-e633fba1b324/volume/python_1565725718142/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d698b2ce-b4b9-4fb4-6268-e633fba1b324/volume/python_1565725718142/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d698b2ce-b4b9-4fb4-6268-e633fba1b324/volume/python_1565725718142/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS@rpath/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d698b2ce-b4b9-4fb4-6268-e633fba1b324/volume/python_1565725718142/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d698b2ce-b4b9-4fb4-6268-e633fba1b324/volume/python_1565725718142/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d698b2ce-b4b9-4fb4-6268-e633fba1b324/volume/python_1565725718142/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d698b2ce-b4b9-4fb4-6268-e633fba1b324/volume/python_1565725718142/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d698b2ce-b4b9-4fb4-6268-e633fba1b324/volume/python_1565725718142/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d698b2ce-b4b9-4fb4-6268-e633fba1b324/volume/python_1565725718142/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/../../libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d698b2ce-b4b9-4fb4-6268-e633fba1b324/volume/python_1565725718142/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d698b2ce-b4b9-4fb4-6268-e633fba1b324/volume/python_1565725718142/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d698b2ce-b4b9-4fb4-6268-e633fba1b324/volume/python_1565725718142/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d698b2ce-b4b9-4fb4-6268-e633fba1b324/volume/python_1565725718142/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d698b2ce-b4b9-4fb4-6268-e633fba1b324/volume/python_1565725718142/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d698b2ce-b4b9-4fb4-6268-e633fba1b324/volume/python_1565725718142/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/../../libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d698b2ce-b4b9-4fb4-6268-e633fba1b324/volume/python_1565725718142/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d698b2ce-b4b9-4fb4-6268-e633fba1b324/volume/python_1565725718142/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d698b2ce-b4b9-4fb4-6268-e633fba1b324/volume/python_1565725718142/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d698b2ce-b4b9-4fb4-6268-e633fba1b324/volume/python_1565725718142/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d698b2ce-b4b9-4fb4-6268-e633fba1b324/volume/python_1565725718142/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d698b2ce-b4b9-4fb4-6268-e633fba1b324/volume/python_1565725718142/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d698b2ce-b4b9-4fb4-6268-e633fba1b324/volume/python_1565725718142/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d698b2ce-b4b9-4fb4-6268-e633fba1b324/volume/python_1565725718142/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libffi.6.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)

With the result that

$ /opt/anaconda3/bin/conda
environment variables:
conda info could not be constructed.
KeyError('pkgs_dirs')
An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.
```

## Recent Environment History

**conda-meta/history**

```yaml
==> 2022-03-01 15:37:32 <== 
# cmd: /opt/anaconda3/bin/conda update anaconda 
# conda version: 4.11.0 
# update specs: ['anaconda'] 
# neutered specs: ['anaconda']  
==> 2022-03-01 16:01:48 <== 
# cmd: /opt/anaconda3/bin/conda update anaconda-navigator 
# conda version: 4.11.0 
# update specs: ['anaconda-navigator']
==> 2022-11-17 18:42:41 <== 
# cmd: /opt/anaconda3/bin/conda install --yes --json --force-pscheck --prefix /opt/anaconda3 anaconda-navigator==2.3.2 
# conda version: 4.11.0 
# update specs: ['anaconda-navigator==2.3.2']  
==> 2022-12-08 04:32:09 <== 
# cmd: /opt/anaconda3/bin/conda update conda 
# conda version: 22.9.0 
# update specs: ['conda']
```

I think the problem occurred after my last update, which was a few weeks ago in December and concerning Conda.

Comment: This seems like missing important info. Presumably this is an old installation? e.g., Python 3.7 isn’t really supported anymore. It might help to see some recent history of your **base**. If `conda list --revisions` isn’t working, then you can manually inspect the `conda-meta/history` file in the **base** prefix. I think sharing the last 5 revisions could help. In the end, you may need to upgrade `python` and `conda` in **base**, which you would need something like Micromamba to do given the broken `conda`. Also, check you don’t have the `conda` package multiple places.

Comment: @merv Here's the history for 2022 (continued on a second comment):

`==> 2022-03-01 15:37:32 <==
# cmd: /opt/anaconda3/bin/conda update anaconda
# conda version: 4.11.0
# update specs: ['anaconda']
# neutered specs: ['anaconda']

==> 2022-03-01 16:01:48 <==
# cmd: /opt/anaconda3/bin/conda update anaconda-navigator
# conda version: 4.11.0
# update specs: ['anaconda-navigator']`

Comment: @merv Here's the rest of the history:

`==> 2022-11-17 18:42:41 <==
# cmd: /opt/anaconda3/bin/conda install --yes --json --force-pscheck --prefix /opt/anaconda3 anaconda-navigator==2.3.2
# conda version: 4.11.0
# update specs: ['anaconda-navigator==2.3.2']

==> 2022-12-08 04:32:09 <==
# cmd: /opt/anaconda3/bin/conda update conda
# conda version: 22.9.0
# update specs: ['conda']`

Comment: @merv I think the problem occurred after my last update, which was a few weeks ago in December and concerning `conda`. How would I use **Micromamba** to upgrade `python` and `conda` in **base**?

Comment: Thanks for adding that info! In the future, please add requested info (especially stuff needing formatting) to the question rather than as comments. As for Micromamba, there are [directions in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54563455/570918).

Comment: @merv Thank you for the advice concerning the requested info. Alas, I tried all the directions in the link you posted and then some without anything working for me. I continued to get the same error. So I used `sudo rm -rf <anaconda3 path>` to remove anaconda3 from my computer (including the `export path` line in my bash profile) and then installed the newest anaconda available. Things are working now, and I've recreated my environments.

Comment: Okay, sorry it didn’t work out without nuking the install. Sometimes though, that’s simply the fastest way for users to get things back to working order. Repairing broken Conda installs can be rather surgical; and it’s not really something people need to do often (I’ve only done it twice after using Conda for more than six years).