# First I had an error with GLIBCXX_3.4.30 and now I can't create any more conda environments

Tags: r, bash, anaconda, conda

I was using R in RStudio under a conda environment with various bioconductor packages. But suddenly I ran into this error when I tried to load a package:

```
ImportError: /home/user/anaconda3/envs/dmcgb/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-13.so.1)
```

It is not the first time that I have this error so I did what I did before to solve it. I deleted the environment and tried to recreate it but ran into another error when I ran `conda create -n dashboard_2 -c conda-forge -c bioconda r-seurat=4* bioconductor-enrichplot bioconductor-clusterprofiler bioconductor-deseq2`:

```
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(740): An error occurred while installing package 'bioconda::bioconductor-genomeinfodbdata-1.2.9-r42hdfd78af_0'.                                                                     
Rolling back transaction: done                                                                                                                                                                                     
class: LinkError                                                                                                                                                                                                   
message:                                                                                                                                                                                                           
post-link script failed for package bioconda::bioconductor-genomeinfodbdata-1.2.9-r42hdfd78af_0                                                                                                                    
location of failed script: /home/ezequielp/anaconda3/envs/dashboard_2/bin/.bioconductor-genomeinfodbdata-post-link.sh                                                                                              
==> script messages <==                                                                                                                                                                                            
<None>                                                                                                                                                                                                             
==> script output <==                                                                                                                                                                                              
stdout: /home/ezequielp/anaconda3/envs/dashboard_2/share/genomeinfodbdata-1.2.9/"GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.9.tar.gz": OK                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
stderr: ++ dirname -- /home/ezequielp/anaconda3/envs/dashboard_2/bin/installBiocDataPackage.sh                                                                                                                     
+ SCRIPT_DIR=/home/ezequielp/anaconda3/envs/dashboard_2/bin/../share/bioconductor-data-packages                                                                                                                    
+ json=/home/ezequielp/anaconda3/envs/dashboard_2/bin/../share/bioconductor-data-packages/dataURLs.json                                                                                                            
++ yq '."genomeinfodbdata-1.2.9".fn' /home/ezequielp/anaconda3/envs/dashboard_2/bin/../share/bioconductor-data-packages/dataURLs.json                                                                              
+ FN='"GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.9.tar.gz"'                                                                                                                                                                             
+ IFS=                                                                                                                                                                                                             
+ read -r value                                                                                                                                                                                                    
++ yq '."genomeinfodbdata-1.2.9".urls[]' /home/ezequielp/anaconda3/envs/dashboard_2/bin/../share/bioconductor-data-packages/dataURLs.json                                                                          
+ URLS+=($value)                                                                                                                                                                                                   
+ IFS=                                                                                                                                                                                                             
+ read -r value                                                                                                                                                                                                    
+ URLS+=($value)                                                                                                                                                                                                   
+ IFS=                                                                                                                                                                                                             
+ read -r value                                                                                                                                                                                                    
+ URLS+=($value)                                                                                                                                                                                                   
+ IFS=                                                                                                                                                                                                             
+ read -r value                                                                                                                                                                                                    
++ yq '."genomeinfodbdata-1.2.9".md5' /home/ezequielp/anaconda3/envs/dashboard_2/bin/../share/bioconductor-data-packages/dataURLs.json                                                                             
+ MD5='"7cc138cfb74665fdfa8d1c244eac4879"'                                                                                                                                                                         
+ STAGING=/home/ezequielp/anaconda3/envs/dashboard_2/share/genomeinfodbdata-1.2.9                                                                                                                                  
+ mkdir -p /home/ezequielp/anaconda3/envs/dashboard_2/share/genomeinfodbdata-1.2.9                                                                                                                                 
+ TARBALL='/home/ezequielp/anaconda3/envs/dashboard_2/share/genomeinfodbdata-1.2.9/"GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.9.tar.gz"'                                                                                                
+ SUCCESS=0                                                                                                                                                                                                        
+ for URL in ${URLS[@]}                                                                                                                                                                                            
++ echo '"https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.16/data/annotation/src/contrib/GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.9.tar.gz"'                                                                                                       
++ tr -d '"'                                                                                                                                                                                                       
+ URL=https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.16/data/annotation/src/contrib/GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.9.tar.gz                                                                                                             
++ echo '"7cc138cfb74665fdfa8d1c244eac4879"'                                                                                                                                                                       
++ tr -d '"'                                                                                                                                                                                                       
+ MD5=7cc138cfb74665fdfa8d1c244eac4879                                                                                                                                                                             
+ curl -L https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.16/data/annotation/src/contrib/GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.9.tar.gz                                                                                                         
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current                                                                                                                                    
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed                                                                                                                                      
100 11.1M  100 11.1M    0     0  11.9M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 11.9M                                                                                                                                     
+ [[ 0 == 0 ]]                                                                                                                                                                                                     
++ uname -s                                                                                                                                                                                                        
+ [[ Linux == \L\i\n\u\x ]]                                                                                                                                                                                        
+ md5sum -c                                                                                                                                                                                                        
+ SUCCESS=1                                                                                                                                                                                                        
+ break                                                                                                                                                                                                            
+ [[ 1 != 1 ]]                                                                                                                                                                                                     
+ R CMD INSTALL --library=/home/ezequielp/anaconda3/envs/dashboard_2/lib/R/library '/home/ezequielp/anaconda3/envs/dashboard_2/share/genomeinfodbdata-1.2.9/"GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.9.tar.gz"'
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
Calls: source -> file
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  cannot open file 'renv/activate.R': No such file or directory
Execution halted

return code: 1

kwargs:
{}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ezequielp/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1132, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ezequielp/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 69, in main_subshell
    exit_code = do_call(args, p)
  File "/home/ezequielp/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 122, in do_call
    return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
  File "/home/ezequielp/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/notices/core.py", line 121, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ezequielp/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/cli/main_create.py", line 41, in execute
    install(args, parser, 'create')
  File "/home/ezequielp/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 334, in install
    handle_txn(unlink_link_transaction, prefix, args, newenv)
  File "/home/ezequielp/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 363, in handle_txn
    unlink_link_transaction.execute()
  File "/home/ezequielp/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/core/link.py", line 283, in execute
    self._execute(tuple(chain(*chain(*zip(*self.prefix_action_groups.values())))))
  File "/home/ezequielp/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/core/link.py", line 756, in _execute
    raise CondaMultiError(
conda.CondaMultiErrorclass: LinkError
message:
post-link script failed for package bioconda::bioconductor-genomeinfodbdata-1.2.9-r42hdfd78af_0
location of failed script: /home/ezequielp/anaconda3/envs/dashboard_2/bin/.bioconductor-genomeinfodbdata-post-link.sh
==> script messages <==
<None>
==> script output <==
stdout: /home/ezequielp/anaconda3/envs/dashboard_2/share/genomeinfodbdata-1.2.9/"GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.9.tar.gz": OK

stderr: ++ dirname -- /home/ezequielp/anaconda3/envs/dashboard_2/bin/installBiocDataPackage.sh
+ SCRIPT_DIR=/home/ezequielp/anaconda3/envs/dashboard_2/bin/../share/bioconductor-data-packages
+ json=/home/ezequielp/anaconda3/envs/dashboard_2/bin/../share/bioconductor-data-packages/dataURLs.json
++ yq '."genomeinfodbdata-1.2.9".fn' /home/ezequielp/anaconda3/envs/dashboard_2/bin/../share/bioconductor-data-packages/dataURLs.json
+ FN='"GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.9.tar.gz"'
+ IFS=
+ read -r value
++ yq '."genomeinfodbdata-1.2.9".urls[]' /home/ezequielp/anaconda3/envs/dashboard_2/bin/../share/bioconductor-data-packages/dataURLs.json
+ URLS+=($value)
+ IFS=
+ read -r value
+ URLS+=($value)
+ IFS=
+ read -r value
+ URLS+=($value)
+ IFS=
+ read -r value
++ yq '."genomeinfodbdata-1.2.9".md5' /home/ezequielp/anaconda3/envs/dashboard_2/bin/../share/bioconductor-data-packages/dataURLs.json
+ MD5='"7cc138cfb74665fdfa8d1c244eac4879"'
+ STAGING=/home/ezequielp/anaconda3/envs/dashboard_2/share/genomeinfodbdata-1.2.9
+ mkdir -p /home/ezequielp/anaconda3/envs/dashboard_2/share/genomeinfodbdata-1.2.9
+ TARBALL='/home/ezequielp/anaconda3/envs/dashboard_2/share/genomeinfodbdata-1.2.9/"GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.9.tar.gz"'
+ SUCCESS=0
+ for URL in ${URLS[@]}
++ echo '"https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.16/data/annotation/src/contrib/GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.9.tar.gz"'
++ tr -d '"'
+ URL=https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.16/data/annotation/src/contrib/GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.9.tar.gz
++ echo '"7cc138cfb74665fdfa8d1c244eac4879"'
++ tr -d '"'
+ MD5=7cc138cfb74665fdfa8d1c244eac4879
+ curl -L https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.16/data/annotation/src/contrib/GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.9.tar.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 11.1M  100 11.1M    0     0  11.9M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 11.9M
+ [[ 0 == 0 ]]
++ uname -s
+ [[ Linux == \L\i\n\u\x ]]
+ md5sum -c
+ SUCCESS=1
+ break
+ [[ 1 != 1 ]]
+ R CMD INSTALL --library=/home/ezequielp/anaconda3/envs/dashboard_2/lib/R/library '/home/ezequielp/anaconda3/envs/dashboard_2/share/genomeinfodbdata-1.2.9/"GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.9.tar.gz"'
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
Calls: source -> file
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  cannot open file 'renv/activate.R': No such file or directory
Execution halted

return code: 1

kwargs:
{}

: <exception str() failed>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ezequielp/anaconda3/bin/conda", line 13, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/ezequielp/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 112, in main
    return conda_exception_handler(main, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ezequielp/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1432, in conda_exception_handler
    return_value = exception_handler(func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ezequielp/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1135, in __call__
    return self.handle_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
  File "/home/ezequielp/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1164, in handle_exception
    return self.handle_application_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
  File "/home/ezequielp/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1178, in handle_application_exception
    self._print_conda_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
  File "/home/ezequielp/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1182, in _print_conda_exception
    print_conda_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
  File "/home/ezequielp/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1109, in print_conda_exception
    stderrlog.error("\n%r\n", exc_val)
  File "/home/ezequielp/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/logging/__init__.py", line 1506, in error
    self._log(ERROR, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ezequielp/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/logging/__init__.py", line 1624, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "/home/ezequielp/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/logging/__init__.py", line 1633, in handle
    if (not self.disabled) and self.filter(record):
  File "/home/ezequielp/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/logging/__init__.py", line 821, in filter
    result = f.filter(record)
  File "/home/ezequielp/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/gateways/logging.py", line 48, in filter
    record.msg = record.msg % new_args
  File "/home/ezequielp/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/__init__.py", line 99, in __repr__
    errs.append(e.__repr__())
  File "/home/ezequielp/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/__init__.py", line 54, in __repr__
    return f"{self.__class__.__name__}: {self}"
  File "/home/ezequielp/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/__init__.py", line 58, in __str__
    return str(self.message % self._kwargs)
ValueError: unsupported format character 'T' (0x54) at index 2061
```

But I lied, because before reinstalling the environment I tried the following:

`conda install libgcc` <-- didn't work

`conda update libstdcxx-ng` <-- didn't work

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/your/path/to/conda/env/lib` <-- didn't work

`conda install -c conda-forge gcc=12.1.0` <-- didn't work

`strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX_3.4.30` <-- returned nothing

After trying all that and it didn't work. I tried to reinstall the conda environment. And there I found the errors that I said. To solve that, I performed:

uninstall and re-install anaconda <-- didn't work

`conda clean --all` <-- didn't work

I need help. I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Generally, you shouldn't ever have to mess with dynamically-linked libraries manually like this - it's more a symptom of a bad configuration or a broken package (it happens). Are your channels [configured to use Bioconda properly](https://bioconda.github.io/#usage)?

Comment: Can you roll back your changes? `conda list --revisions` then `conda install --revision <n>` (fill in `<n>` appropriately). Also, please add `conda list` for the environment you are debugging.

Comment: The problem is I don't have any environment now because I'm not able to create a new one. I noticed that this happens only when I create environments with bioconductor packages. But I followed the @merv suggestion and didn't work either

Comment: Personally, I would either 1) remove Anaconda and install Mambaforge, which is more compatible with Bioconda; or 2) try repairing **base** using Micromamba (some directions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54563455/570918)). I would prefer **(1)** if I didn't have many environments and could get away with a *clean* install. I would do **(2)** only if I have been using Conda for a long time and have a clear idea what needs to be repaired in **base**.

Comment: Yes, using mamba was my other option. I think option (1) could work. And I'm more sure now that you mention it @merv. Thanks!

Comment: Update: Mamba didn't work either. I'm getting the same error @merv :(